# is there a yarn alternative for npm audit?

Tags: security, npm, dependencies, yarnpkg, audit

need pinned resolution feature of yarn, but also want to audit with `npm audit`? Is there a yarn alternative to `npm audit`? Or, alternately, will pinning resolutions of dependencies of dependencies work in `npm`?

Comment: check it out my post https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-fix-security-vulnerabilities-in-npm-yarn-dependencies/

Comment: You might want to change the accepted answer as the situation has changed.

Comment: the current accepted answer is to just use yarn now

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`yarn audit` / `yarn install --audit` has been available since yarn@1.12.0

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/tag/v1.12.0

Unfortunately no `--fix` option yet, but as workaround you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-audit-fix

Comment: If you are seeing `Command "audit" not found` upgrade your yarn install.

`npm install --global yarn`

`npm upgrade --global yarn`

Comment: There currently is no "fix" option of `yarn audit`, as you would with `npm audit fix`.

Follow issue here: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7075

Answer (score 217):

Yarn doesn't have `npm audit fix`.

But here's how to do it by using `npm` – temporarily.

1. Generate a `package-lock.json` file without installing node modules

```sh
npm i --package-lock-only
```

2. Fix the packages and update the `package-lock.json` file

```sh
npm audit fix
```

3. Delete the `yarn.lock` file and convert `package-lock.json` file into `yarn.lock`

```sh
rm yarn.lock
yarn import
```

4. Delete the `package-lock.json` file

```sh
rm package-lock.json
```

### For example:

```sh
yarn audit

38363 vulnerabilities found - Packages audited: 908342
Severity: 38352 Low | 11 Moderate
```

(I know. `react-scripts` is crazy...)

```
npm audit
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOLOCK
npm ERR! audit Neither npm-shrinkwrap.json nor package-lock.json found: Cannot audit a project without a lockfile
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
```

```sh
npm i --package-lock-only

...
added 266 packages, removed 354 packages, updated 1653 packages, moved 1 package and audited 913793 packages in 54.304s
found 495 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

```sh
npm audit fix

...
added 267 packages from 152 contributors, removed 355 packages and updated 1712 packages in 92.849s

50 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

fixed 211 of 495 vulnerabilities in 913793 scanned packages
  284 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
```

```sh
git status -s

?? package-lock.json
```

```sh
yarn import

yarn import v1.21.1
info found npm package-lock.json, converting to yarn.lock
...
success Saved lockfile.
✨  Done in 25.61s
```

```sh
rm package-lock.json
```

Comment: Seems that `yarn import` doesn't work when using a monorepo which refers to other local packages. It looks like it trying the fetch the packages from the npm registry. Any tips to make this works?

Comment: This package https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-audit-fix is based on the above answer turning it into a single command `yarn-audit-fix`, so it should simplify the above for you.

Comment: To me, it looks like for yarn 3, `yarn upgrade-interactive` is an alternative (though it does not limit itself to only security updates!)

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can use `yarn audit` to audit for vulnerability but you can't fix the Vulnerabilities by using `yarn audit fix` as you can do in `npm audit fix`.

To fix the Vulnerabilities in `yarn.lock` file you have to reinstall the package(which is carrying the Vulnerability) to its newer version by using `yarn add package_name`

you can read the issue here => https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7075

Comment: that thread was locked a new one should be created. they aren't taking this seriously.

Answer (score 12):

I thinks that it's not ready on yarn. You can refer to the following issue.
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5808

Comment: what about an accepted 3rd party replacement in the meantime?

Comment: https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-fix-security-vulnerabilities-in-npm-yarn-dependencies/

Answer (score 8):

#### 1st

Always use source control and check in your `package.json` as well as your `yarn.lock` and/or `package-lock.json` first and start with all committed files, so you can roll back if needed with ease.

#### How about a solution that does not add dependencies to your project (nor installing a third party library)?

```
yarn outdated         # view
yarn audit            # view 
yarn install --audit  # install
```

#### Prefer an interactive way to upgrade selectively with ease?

```
yarn upgrade-interactive
```

#### That might do all you require.

Oddly, you might find with a `yarn audit` following that command you still have some vulnerabilities not mentioned from the command `yarn upgrade-interactive`. In this case I'd first consider this:

```
yarn upgrade-interactive --latest
```

[where that can be found](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4390#issuecomment-328728114)

Still not quite good enough?
```
yarn upgrade --latest
```

I've seen a lot of other potential solutions, previously I'd just switch to `npm` from `yarn` temporarily as some users have suggested, then switch back to `yarn`. This has worked fine for me too. (Though annoying and not elegant)

There are packages out there that don't require install to run.
I haven't tried this one, it might be good too:

```
npm_config_yes=true npx yarn-audit-fix
```

[ref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-audit-fix)

The key here is you are using `npx` to avoid installing as a dependency.

Many more solutions are possible. `npm` and `yarn` both are package managers, dependency management is a very difficult thing to do, automagically fixing these dependencies will always be a difficult problem to solve. Thus I recommend a little research on how they are actually solving these problems if you have the time. You might find yourself not liking how they do things.

Ultimately, as long as you can roll back you can try a lot of these out and see for yourself. Some packages severity might not need fixing, sometimes libraries do not have solutions available yet, then you need to consider removing their usage in your codebase. In theory, less is more, less dependency on libraries, which use libraries, which use libraries.... becomes a much smaller surface for attackers to target. Also, it's not advisable to use libraries from untrusted sources, `npm`, `yarn` and more cannot know everything, nor right away, so keep that in consideration too.

Answer (score 8):

I created a script command into the package.json file to fix it. It creates a copy of yarn.lock as package-lock.json, removes the issues and then re-creates yarn.lock.

```
"resolve:security": "npm i --package-lock-only && npm audit fix && rm yarn.lock && yarn import && rm package-lock.json",
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

do a `yarn audit` and find the package(s) with vulnerabilities,

if they are in your package.json file

- fix their version from there

else

- they are dependencies of your packages so add this to package.json file

```
"resolutions": {
    "**/package-name": "known-good-version",
    "**/**/package-name": "known-good-version"
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `yarn audit` as mentioned in the other answers, however, there is a different way to solve them...

You will need to add the `resolution` instruction to specify the version of the library that the vunerability was solved and the path of the dependency (because the library can be a dependency of another dependency, for example:

Considering part of some package.json below

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "left-pad": "1.0.0",
    "c": "file:../c-1",
    "d2": "file:../d2-1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "d2/left-pad": "1.1.1",
    "c/**/left-pad": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

More details can be checked directly in the documentation: [Doc](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/)

Answer (score 3):

Yarn also has `yarn audit` mechanism, but it doesn't have `yarn audit fix` mechanism. So in most cases you have to fix these issues manually. This is how it works. For example we'll demonstrate it using minimist package:

- Add a `resolutions` key in your `package.json` file:

1. Adding dependency(say `minimist`) directly as key value .This resolution will override `minimist` entirely in your project.

```json
{
  "resolutions": {
    "minimist": "^1.2.5"
  }
}
```

2. In most cases, there can be multiple dependencies in a project that use the same secondary dependency, however, they might use different versions of those dependencies. Thankfully, yarn/npm allows us to have selective dependency resolutions.

The format to define `resolutions` is the following:

```json
/* package.json */
{
  "resolutions": {
    "<package>/**/<dependency>": "<version>"
  }
}
```

Let’s say for example, we have a dependency `A` and `B` and both of them depend upon another dependency `C`.

Then our resolutions field would look like:

```json
/* package.json */
{
  "resolutions": {
    "A/**/C": "2.0.3", // A works fine with the latest version of C
    "B/**/C": "1.9.0" // latest stable version for C for dependency B
  }
}
```

Let's further see how it works with an example of `package-merge-lodash-4` package. If audit says that `lodash@3.9.3` has vulnerabilities and suggests us to upgrade `lodash@3.9.3 -> 4.17.12`.

We can write our json file's resolutions only for the concerned package as below:

```json
{
  "resolutions": {
    "package-merge-lodash-4/**/lodash": "4.17.12"
  }
}
```

3. How to use [Selective dependency resolutions in npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions)?

> add `npm-force-resolutions` to the `preinstall` script after you added `resolutions` key to `package.json` file, so that it patches the `package-lock` file before every `npm install` you run:

```json
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
}
```

To confirm that the right version was installed, use the below command

```sh
npm ls <vulnerable dependency>
```

```sh
npm ls lodash
```

Resources:

- [Selective dependency resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions)
- [Yarn - How to fix security issues](https://javascriptbit.com/yarn-audit-fix-security-issues/)
- [How to fix security vulnerabilities in NPM/Yarn dependencies](https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-fix-security-vulnerabilities-in-npm-yarn-dependencies/)
- [Yarn audit fix: workaround](https://dev.to/antongolub/yarn-audit-fix-workaround-i2a)
- [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/10907720)
- [Semver explained - why is there a caret (^) in my package.json?](https://bytearcher.com/articles/semver-explained-why-theres-a-caret-in-my-package-json/)

Comment: This is very detailed, thank you. This should be the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yarn doesn't support the fix at the moment,

## Workaround

- create a package-lock.json file using npm.
- fix the packages
- remove the `package-lock.json`.

.

```
npm i --package-lock-only
npm audit fix
rm package-lock.json
```

and start

```
yarn start
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using,

```
yarn upgrade-interactive --latest
```

Will install all the latest dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

If using yarn3, you can do:

```
yarn npm audit
```