# Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I created the default IntelliJ IDEA React project and got this:

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/user/Programming Documents/WebServer/untitled/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/user/Programming Documents/WebServer/untitled/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/Users/user/Programming Documents/WebServer/untitled/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /Users/user/Programming Documents/WebServer/untitled/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /Users/user/Programming Documents/WebServer/untitled/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /Users/user/Programming Documents/WebServer/untitled/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/user/Programming Documents/WebServer/untitled/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/user/Programming Documents/WebServer/untitled/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
/Users/user/Programming Documents/WebServer/untitled/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^
```

It seems to be a recent issue - *[webpack ran into this 4 days ago and is still working on it](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532)*.

Comment: Do the workarounds mentioned in that issue link work for you?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans There are no workarounds in the issue by Webpack :/ This is why I asked this question.

Comment: Yes there are? https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-947012063 was posted 6 days ago (and there's lots of followup since then from people asking exactly how to use that, with lots of explanations by several folks).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans my bad! i saw that and thought 'but where' and looked for an answer but only found people asking what i wanted to know. My bad!

Comment: If you have come here with this error on NodeJS v18.x, the cause is the same. See https://web.archive.org/web/20220412174915/https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#support-for-weak-or-compromised-algorithms for details as to the cause, and follow the instructions to enable the OpenSSL legacy provider https://web.archive.org/web/20220416014625/https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--openssl-legacy-provider

Comment: Have you tried to update to the latest version of webpack? I'm not sure about the cause of this bug, but it was already fixed on the latest version.

Comment: just run the compatible version with the current project
nvm exec [v] [npm run dev] || [node app.js] 
check nvm -h examples

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69691525/3426192

Comment: I don't want to hijack the comments section, but I think it's crazy that the top 10 answers recommend downgrading your security or sticking to an outdated node version when for most people facing this issue (and the OP) the solution is simply [upgrading `react-scripts` to >5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71334532/2525299)!

Comment: @neopostmodern, sometimes projects can't be easily upgraded, sometimes there are budget or time constraints, etc. Downgrading is, sometimes, the way to go. Not everything is perfect or easy.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue that real-world constrains or setups without `react-scripts` don't exist, but they can't possibly reflect/justify the current order of answers. I'd expect those to be "In case the obvious solution doesn't work, try these workarounds" kind of answers you get when you scroll down.

Comment: Maybe someone finds this useful, I have been using `"webpack": "^5.7.0",` and upgraded to `"webpack": "^5.88.2",` and it worked. I presume the transient dependencies were updated (possibly due to security issues).

Answer (score 1120, accepted):

In your package.json: change this line

```json
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

to

```json
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
```

Comment: but note that `--openssl-legacy-provider` means you are now almost certainly [running with known insecure SSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/OSSL_PROVIDER-legacy.html), so this might mitigate the symptom, but it probably doesn't fix the underlying problem.

Comment: But of cause, this is acceptable when running localhost. In the newly released VS 2022, starting a react-app from scratch, having VS 2022 creating a self-signed certificate for you, still causes the sample project to crash. This is also an issue when creating a react-project from scratch using NPM commandline "npx create-react-app react-core-test". I testet this in two distinct environments runnin WIndows 10 and Windows 11.

Comment: See Ashok's answer. It's the correct solution to keep SSL working without vulnerabilities and it worked for me.

Comment: I don't understand the implication that, somehow, using node 16 with openssl 1.x would be more secure than using node 17 with openssl 3 in legacy mode. OpenSSL made something stricter in v3. You're either defeating that restriction one way, or the other. Both approaches are probably equally insecure.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v17.0.0/

Comment: This has been solved in react-scripts 5: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71334532/2525299

Comment: thanks, adding this parameter worked in my latest node version. I am impressed how node / react related commands keep breaking months after we create a solution and try to maintain it.

Comment: Thanks, I had to modify similarly in my nextjs app
"dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--openssl-legacy-provider\" node server.js",

Comment: Thanks! This worked like charm. But this means the project is somewhat insecure.

Comment: In case anyone found this while working on a React Native project and attempting to build through XCode (likely on an M1 Mac), you can add this node arg in `node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh`. Mine was found at line `103`, but of course that may vary based on versions, &c. I just updated the line to read: `[ -z "$NODE_ARGS" ] && export NODE_ARGS="--openssl-legacy-provider"` and I was instantly back in business. Note that this may well be overwritten after each `npm install` or `yarn` run, and would likely be ignored by your version control as it lives in `node_modules`.

Comment: what I need to change in case ReactNative?

Comment: This doesn't work for Webpack.

Comment: Worked for me, so hacky or not, this is the goto solution for anyone wanting to try out some react project with this problem.

Comment: I needed to do a `npm audit fix --force` first to get this working.

Comment: thanks a lot, i use all methods above but none of them works, only working when changing script command

Answer (score 2670):

You can try one of these:

**1. Downgrade to Node.js v16.**

- You can reinstall the current LTS version from Node.js’ [website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).
- You can also use [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). For Windows, use [`nvm-windows`](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

**2. Enable legacy OpenSSL provider.**

On Unix-like (Linux, macOS, Git bash, etc.):

```bash
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

On Windows command prompt:

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

On PowerShell:

```
$env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--openssl-legacy-provider"
```

[Reference](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-947012063)

Comment: where do i put this?

Comment: @Evergreen you have to define the variable when you are building --> in your npm run command (you can use export, SET or cross-env depending on your OS)

Comment: For me this command fails `/usr/local/Cellar/node/17.0.1/bin/node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS`

Comment: what about ```docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/usr/src -w="/usr/src" node:latest export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && yarn build```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 11: exec: export: not found @ajoy-karmakar

Comment: Worked for me, windows 10 using gitbash terminal (with the unix commands option enabled during installation)

Comment: This solution is not recomended, try to uninstall Node.js version 17+ and reinstall the Node.js version 16+.

Comment: did `set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`
It's giving the same error

Comment: @AbdulBasitRishi This worked well, thank you for posting. It seems like a very telling solution... is this an issue buried within the newest Node version or is it just incidental that reverting to the older version solves it?

Comment: Hi, please edit this and add windows command --> set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider. Thank you!

Comment: For many using Linux doing a simple `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` is not a very efficient solution. Once your terminal session ends that change goes away. If you wanted to make this permanent you'd have to add it to something like  ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc. 

Regardless, as mentioned by others I think setting an environment variable to work around the problem feels a bit hacky. Better to revert to LTS version of node in my opinion.

Comment: I've this problem with node 16.13.2

Comment: Downgrading to 16.13.0 is not enough, and it still won't let you use `--openssl-legacy-provider`.

To use this parameter, you must be on v17 and up, and the parameter must be placed inside your `package.json`, it won't allow you to just place it in the `NODE_OPTIONS` env var for security reasons.

And then it still doesn't work.

This will only become a bigger problem as more people move onto the v16 LTS as a lot of projects still depend on Webpack 4

Comment: I'm using  `nvm`, so I just switched versions to: `16` and it worked perfectly. It wasn't required for me to define the SSL env variables.

Comment: How did you switch versions?

Comment: Please go through the answer again. I have updated the answer.

Comment: If you use multiple versions of node, it's best to use nvm and uninstall node all together. Then use node version manager to install the latest version using `nvm install lts && nvm use lts`

Comment: On PowerShell, `$env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--openssl-legacy-provider"`. Upgrading to 18.4.0 didn't help.

Comment: On Mac Monterrey, this env. variable mentioned in the answer solved it: `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`

Comment: The answer by @rob-juurlink was the only one which was feasible for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/72219174/7583539. It does not require downgrading nodejs nor does it require updating all the underlying webpack stuff etc nor does it require the `--openssl-legacy-provider` flag. It targets the root problem (dropped support for MD4 in OpenSSL 3) and fixes it in a reasonably elegant manner.

Comment: **WARNING: WARNING: WARNING: WARNING: WARNING: WARNING: WARNING: WARNING: If you use the `yarn` tool, it will default to `/usr/bin/node` and won't properly follow your `PATH`. I wasted an HOUR downgrading my Node to all kinds of old versions via the `n` tool. I still kept getting the error. Finally I uninstalled the distro's `nodejs` package and NOW Yarn realizes I want to be using the `n` version in `/usr/local/bin/node` instead. The error is fixed. There is probably a way to tell Yarn which Node version to use but I had just assumed it would figure that out from `PATH`, meh.**

Comment: I get `/usr/bin/node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS` on Fedora 35.

Comment: Adding `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` to Home/.zshrc (MAC / Linux Manjaro or any other distro with Zsh) will avoid putting it every time

Comment: combining the two options worked for me

Comment: `echo 'export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider' >> ~/.zshrc`  works for me. Don't forget to reopen terminal

Comment: This solution is not recomended, try to uninstall Node.js version 17+ and reinstall the Node.js version..

Comment: this actually, helped me for my project that's been lasting for months. However, I feel it's not the best way as I can't install any dependency for my newly created project.

Comment: Consider the warnings in this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027407/1459653 - answer before doing this.

Comment: if you are doing above steps, above error will solve. but new error will comes  Line 6:    'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope

Comment: you can change npm run start in package.json:  "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start", that works as well and doesn't require you to change node versions

Comment: This is not a solution, it's the opposite of a solution! This will take away all the benefits of upgrading to a new version with all its security updates. Please don't do this! The real solution is no where to be found so far!

Comment: No need to downgrade. I'm using node.js 18 with project built with probably node 14. Injecting the parameters into your start script only fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I added the following line to my `.zshrc` file and then restarted my session:

`export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`

Comment: If the project has other dependencies that relies on the React version you are currently in, then no need to downgrade. just add the  '''--openssl-legacy-provider start''' to the react-scripts start.

Comment: This worked for me.  I didn't try it sooner because I though since 18 is LTS, it shouldn't require downgrading.  Why is this STILL an issue?

Comment: found that only version 16.13.0 working in this case

Comment: Downgrading worked for me (`nvm install 16 && nvm use 16`)!

Comment: For me `set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` was all I had to do. No downgrading needed.

Comment: It's fairly recent, but Storybook 7.x release candidate has been released. It's built on newer versions and doesn't suffer this issue. You could attempt an upgrade to it: https://storybook.js.org/docs/7.0/react/get-started/install

Comment: I was on node 19 but then downgrading to 16.18.1 helped me fix the issue.

Comment: I had this issue when using `webpack-dev-server`, and using `nvm` to downgrade Node from v19 to v16.20.0 solved it. Thanks buddy!

Comment: In my Mac, `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` fix the problem.

Comment: I have Windows. I typed the special command for Windows in the command line, but I still got an error. I ran the command for Linux in git bash and the problem was solved!

Comment: I encountered this issue in my Windows 10 with `node v18.16.0`. The `set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`  fixes the issue for me.

Comment: `nvm use 14.21.2` solved my issue

Comment: So, how can I undo "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider"?

Comment: On **Windows** when working on a **Preact** project I needed to modify the `"scripts"` section in the **package.json** from `"dev": "preact watch",` to `"dev": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && preact watch"`. It could be similar for  React projects.

Comment: Downgrading alone worked for me on Mac. Thank you

Comment: i used it without `--` and my app works with node 16.20.1; `cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=openssl-legacy-provider ...`

Comment: I'm using Mac and `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` worked for me.

Comment: I had this error when running a legasy angular app in windows.  I use a dos batch file to launch the app, so just added this before the `ng server` command:  
```set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider```

Comment: `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` doesn't work with `node` below `18`

Comment: This worked for me with node v18.18. Thanks!

Comment: I've added it into the `.npmrc` file which I got from this comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40455#issuecomment-1527619752

Comment: node version was the issue for me. Changed it using `nvm use ##`

Comment: it works for me after 24 hours of searching the solution. Thanks @AjoyKarmakar

Comment: it works for me with nodejs version v20.11.0

Comment: This solution worked for us.  We were running `npm run build` within the node:lts container image as part of our GitLab CICD pipeline.  We just added the NODE_OPTIONS variable as a project variable and re-ran the failed job.

Comment: export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
this works for me, thank you!

Comment: Had this issue with an older version of storybook. Starting storybook with `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider start-storybook` worked. Thanks.

Comment: setting ```set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider``` on windows worked for me

Answer (score 1371):

#### Danger

This question has more than 30 answers, most suggesting to either downgrade Node.js to pre v17 or to use the legacy SSL provider. Both of those solutions are *hacks that leave your builds open to security threats*.

#### Reason For The Error

In Node.js v17, the Node.js developers closed a security hole in the SSL provider. This fix was a breaking change that corresponded with similar breaking changes in the SSL packages in NPM. When you attempt to use SSL in Node.js v17 or later without also upgrading those SSL packages in your `package.json`, then you will see this error.

#### The Correct (safe) Solution (for npm users)

Use an up-to-date version of Node.js, and also use packages that are up-to-date with security fixes.

You can first try an update to see if that solves the problem:

```
npm update
```

If that is not enough, for many people, the following command will fix the issue:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

However, be aware that, for complex builds, the above command will pull in breaking security fixes that can *potentially* break your build.

#### Note for Yarn users

Yarn users can use [yarn-audit-fix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-audit-fix) which can be run without installing as a dependency via

```
npm_config_yes=true npx yarn-audit-fix
```

or windows powershell:

```
$env:npm_config_yes = 1; npx yarn-audit-fix
```

#### A less heavy-handed (also correct) solution for Webpack

In your Webpack config, set either of the following:
(See [the ouput.hashFunction docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputhashfunction))

A. (Webpack v5) Set `output.hashFunction = 'xxhash64'`.
B. (Webpack v4) This will depend on [what hash algorithms nodejs supports on your system](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm_options). Some common options you can try are `output.hashFunction = 'sha512'` or `output.hashFunction = 'sha256'`.

See more info [in Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73465262/564406).

Comment: `npm audit fix --force` is the only thing that worked for me, but I also had to upgrade all package dependencies in my project first: https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version/

Comment: I was unable to run an `npm audit fix` because I am using a proxy that doesn't support it. An alternative was to do an `npm audit --regsitry=https://resgistry.npmjs.org` and manually inspect the packages to find the offender (in my case `elliptic`). Look for `Use of a Broken or Risky Cryptographic Algorithm`. Then manually update that package to a non-offending version.

Comment: @LukeHutchison probably upgrading the packages is what fixed it, not the audit...

Comment: @vanowm, the `audit fix --force` upgrades packages in a more heavy-handed way than a regular upgrade. The `--force` flag upgrades even breaking changes, which is what many (perhaps most?) of us who have this problem need to fix the problem (unless using the less heavy-handed option mentioned in Greg's answer).

Comment: @David, in my case using `npm update` what fixed it, the `npm audit fix --force` prior that did nothing...just saying.

Comment: Thank you for the actually sane answer, David.  I'm shocked at the number of answers that suggest downgrading node.

Comment: Guys please use `npm audit fix --force` this works and other options are not safe if you are working on big project

Comment: This solution did absolutely nothing to help me - either the "correct safe solution" or the "less heavy handed solution" - it just wasted my time and I got exactly the same error message after trying these fixes.

Comment: npm audit fix --force 
COMPLETELY BREAKS MY PROJECT!
DAMN

Comment: Yes, it is important to reiterate, *this fix can break your build*. Be aware before trying this heavy-handed fix. The needed security updates are *breaking* changes.

Comment: @JuliusGoddard, I agree.  I am just learning React, following a course released 3 months ago (so relatively up-to-date).  I have no idea what any of this is about.  But I had 72 audit errors before running npm audit fix --force, and I have 72 errors after.  Nothing is fixed.  When I tried adding `output.hashFunction = 'xxhash64'` to my webpack.config.js file (which was not easy to find, BTW), I received this error message:  `(node:12080) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
...
output is not defined`

Comment: @Todd Hoatson I know... the solution is like "don't listen to anyone else, our answer is the best" and it doesn't do anything and screws up people's projects.

Comment: Hi @David, thanks for your insight. The Webpack configuration you offer seems to only work for v5. I'm using Webpack 4 (Nuxt 2) and output doesn't seems to be a rules property. Any advice to do the same configuration with v4 please?

Comment: Hi @Claire, I have edited with some helps for webpack v4. What works for webpack v4 will depend some on what hash functions your system supports, so some people may need to experiment to find an appropriate option. Hope that helps!

Comment: @LukeHutchison the link is dead, did you mean [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/updating-packages-downloaded-from-the-registry)

Comment: If you're using YARN, you'll need to use npm to use this fix, here is some documentation that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60878037/2391795

Comment: For me, using `npm i --package-lock-only` (because I was using yarn) and then using `npm audit fix --force` got me from 28 vulnerabilities to 0, so I'd assume that this answer can work. (and can fail, as the author pointed out)

Comment: BUT then I had to randomly upgrade all my packages and then my build finally worked. So, I guess that besides the npm auto fix, some packages were needing an upgrade, too, but I couldn't know which ones.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue for a Laravel project with webpack.mix.js. Unfortunately none of the options work, and I find it odd that almost everyone suggests downgrading Node. I attempted `npm audit fix`, then executed `npm audit fix --force` which can be a bit more destructive based on project dependencies. Unfortunately the ladder command then broke the project build. Thank you for the suggestions however.

Comment: None of these worked.

Comment: This fix was a breaking change - it made my day!

Comment: npm audit fix --force breaks everything I have, every time I use it.  Nothing will build.   I can start from scratch with create-react-app and that command will break it as well.   Need a npm fix audit fix --force first.   ha

Comment: yarn users can use `yarn-audit-fix` package, it worked for me in terms of fixing audit errors but didn't fix the issue with SSL unfortunately,

Comment: People, welcome to the land of JS development.  Yes, there are complicated dependencies.  If you're not willing to work with them and are happy to live with security holes, please get out of this field.

Comment: If I build an Angular app using "ng build", this "--openssl-legacy-provider" option fixes the build problem (it appeared after Node.js has been upgraded to v18). The generated app is served statically as transpiled js files. Does using this option pose any security thread in this case?

Comment: Security at the expense of usability, comes at the expense of security :)

Comment: I don't know what webpack use hashFunction to do, but I doubt there's any real word security issue, as in [hashFunction](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/?_sm_au_=iVVPr5FsL2wWHrF5qQ2QvKH12pCN0#outputhashfunction)'s documentation itself, it says "You can provide a non-crypto hash function for performance reasons."
So I can hardly agree with "Both of those solutions are hacks that leave your builds open to security threats."

Comment: Thank you for a sane answer.  The number of javascript developers that perpetuate this nonsense is utter insanity.

Comment: `openssl list -digest-algorithms` can check what algorithms can digested for webpack v4

Comment: For me, simply doing `pnpm update` fixed the error, without force

Comment: `npm audit fix`, without force option, worked for me. Thank you for the hint ;)

Comment: @David's fix is completely wrong and doesn't work. There is NO fix for Webpack 4 other than to downgrade Node or to upgrade to Webpack 5. Astonishing this answer is so upvoted when it doesn't work!

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful to see the consequences of this. However in my case I use a package which creates an 'md4' hash (thus trigger that error), and I need Node 18+ for another package so I could see no other way than using the legacy openssl flag.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Too many of the other "solutions" are essentially saying, "Leave the door unlocked." -- when the correct solution is, "Fix the lock."

Answer (score 258):

If we use the current LTS version of Node.js then this error will not come. Downgrade your Node.js version to the current LTS version (16.13.0).

There can be multiple ways to install the required version. One of them is using nvm (Node.js version manager).

- Step 1: Install nvm (if not installed, follow *[Install Node.js Locally with Node Version Manager (nvm)](https://heynode.com/tutorial/install-nodejs-locally-nvm/)*)
- Step 2: `nvm install 16.13.0` (or lts)

Comment: but... why is the new version incompatible with old code? node is one of the biggest programming tools in the world, they wouldn't just create a new version of nodejs that wasn't backwards compatible (i guess they would because they did but you get my point)

Comment: Forceful downgrade

Comment: Thanks, It's great. It worked well after uninstalling nodejs version 17.1.0 and reinstall nodejs version 16.13.0.

Comment: Always use LTS for real applications, it fixed the issue.

Comment: solved after downgrade NodeJs from version 17 to version 16 LTS.

Comment: Is the new LTS after 16 supposed to revert back to old SSL? I am assuming the problem will be the same, just deferred until later, and using LTS 16 is a temporary solution.

Comment: Worked for me, instead of typing the version use `nvm instal lts` and `nvm use lts`.

Comment: This was messing me up too. I had multiple versions installed including v17.2.0. It's best to uninstall versions that are not LTS: `nvm uninstall v17.2.0`

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/ and https://render.com/docs/node-version seem like they'll be helpful for me.

Comment: "I have a Node problem that is.." - "Don't care! Downgrade it". I suggest to create a version number like v1000 and every release the major version decrease. So the best release will be smaller version. Until we reach v0.0

Comment: From today Node 18.12.0 is LTS, so I think a downgrade is not a valid strategy anymore :-(

Comment: So if Node v18 is now LTS, what's the solution now?

Comment: I'm also getting this error when creating a nuxt app and I've just downgraded to version 16.13 https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v16.13.0/
Note: I am only using this for testing purposes

Comment: Someone said: **Always use LTS for real applications, it fixed the issue.**  I upgraded to the latest LTS `Node.js 18.13.0` (See https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/), and it did not fix this issue.  I then tried `npm audit fix --force`  which fixed the issue.  When I ran diffs to see what was updated it was `react-scripts: "^5.0.1"` (previously it was 3.4.0).  One of the answers said the fix was to use react-scripts version 5.

Answer (score 153):

This is the **simplest answer** and **works**.

If you're using `react-scripts` you can now simply upgrade to version 5.0.0 (or above) which seems to have addressed this issue ([it includes a newer version of webpack](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v5.0.0)).

Example:
`npm i react-scripts@latest`

Comment: This fixed the issue for my CI build without going backward on versioning or security (ie increasing tech debt with a loose end in the build). Probably should be the best answer in late 2022.

Comment: I agree this should definitely be the accepted answer! I spent a bunch of time trying to make a webpack.config.js with the output hashFunction etc, and then undoing that and trying to do a config-overrides.js file and react-app-rewired since my environment is in docker: ALL A WASTE OF TIME.

Seriously. Simply do like @neo said above and update react-scripts. Ex. ```npm i react-scripts@latest```

Comment: Not working for me when I run storybook

Comment: Hi @Caeta, does your package.json run react-scripts on start? It would look like this. This is default when you use create-react-app
`"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },`

Comment: This didn't update the webpack version. I still get the same error after updating react-scripts to the latest version.

Comment: @tRuEsAtM have you manually pinned webpack? If you have a recent version of `react-scripts` you should absolutely have `webpack` >=5. Otherwise you might need to open a new question.

Comment: I found gatsby had this issue and a `yarn upgrade gatsby` fixed this issue on node 18.

Comment: For those who uses yarn:  yarn add react-scripts. You might get a core-js error afterwards, then you should run: yarn add core-js

Comment: Thanks! I cannot risk the security of my MVP app.

Comment: upgrading my react-scripts to v5+ worked for me too. (and deleted node_modules and reinstalled afterwards, for good measure)

Answer (score 94):

I had this issue when using [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js).

A disadvantage of using `-openssl-legacy-provider` is that it is not supported by older Node.js versions. Older Node.js versions simply don't run when this flag is provided. 
**But I still want to be compatible with Node.js v16 and older.**

Vue.js uses the [MD4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD4) algorithm to generate hashes (well, actually it's [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) under the hood). MD4 can be easily replaced by [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) for these kind of purposes. The type of algorithm used is hard coded in most places, so there isn't any way to configure another algorithm.

So I came up with another workaround. A function that intercepts the original `createHash()` call from the `crypto` module and replaces it with a modified version. This is at the start of my *vue.config.js* file:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

/**
 * The MD4 algorithm is not available anymore in Node.js 17+ (because of library SSL 3).
 * In that case, silently replace MD4 by the MD5 algorithm.
 */
try {
  crypto.createHash('md4');
} catch (e) {
  console.warn('Crypto "MD4" is not supported anymore by this Node.js version');
  const origCreateHash = crypto.createHash;
  crypto.createHash = (alg, opts) => {
    return origCreateHash(alg === 'md4' ? 'md5' : alg, opts);
  };
}
```

Comment: This almost worked for me, but then some part of my webpack build will use some multi-process node build step. Then you won't be able to inject this "shim" into the spawned `node` instances. I ended up just resolving this at the OpenSSL level: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73904032/809572

Comment: This is the most elegant solution which also solves the use of md4 and uses md5. (see comment of @JoshBowden linking to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73904032/16805 which describes underlying issue.)

Comment: This was the only thing that solved my problem. Ialso have a Vue project. Thank you!

Comment: @RobJuurlink thank you very much, it worked! However I did not understood how overwriting "cripto.createHash" in vue.config.js garantees that this new implementation is that one called latter on (where we have the error). Like, you overwritted this function for THIS cripto instance that you created in in vue.config.js.. How does it work in other classes where crypto is instantiated again? Thanks!

Comment: @Lucas it works because `crypto` is a singleton. Every time a program (in the same NodeJS runtime) calls `require("crypto")` the exact same object is returned.

Comment: This is the best answer : it does not disable security feature and does not need to go back to Node 16. It just properly overwrite the outdated algo. Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, it fixed the issue when I used `serve` command, but `build` didn't work. I spent a day finding out I had to delete and regenerate `yarn.lock` file. Maybe it would save time for somebody

Comment: @TheSaGe you need to insert this script at the start of each of your webpack configs, for me it was inserted in 3 places: webpack.config.js, webpack.dev.babel.js and webpack.prod.babel.js. The prod one is used for build

Comment: What would this look like in the context of a react app, though?
I created a file (create-hash.js) and placed the code inside. Then I ran the command

"node create-hash.js && react-scripts build".

But it still failed with the same error. I'm guessing this didn't apply the fix to the correct instance?? Putting it in index.js didn't work either.

Answer (score 87):

There are a lot of workarounds posted (mostly downgrading Node.js, OpenSSL, or allowing insecure hashing), but the underlying problem is that Webpack's `output.hashFunction` defaults to `md4`, which triggers this error in recent versions of OpenSSL.

From Webpack's [output.hashFunction](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputhashfunction) docs:

> Since Webpack v5.54.0+, `hashFunction` supports `xxhash64` as a faster algorithm, which will be used as default when
> `experiments.futureDefaults` is enabled.

The solution is either:

1. Set `output.hashFunction = 'xxhash64'`
2. Set `experiments.futureDefaults = true`

in your Webpack configuration.

If you're on an older version of Webpack, (prior to v5.54.0) follow the output.hashFunction link above to see what other hashing algorithms are available to you.

Comment: If like myself, you made this change and you were still hitting issues, then check your loaders. `file-loader` and `css-loader` use `md4` by default. You can force them to use another hashing algo when setting the name option like so: `'[name].[sha512:hash:6].[ext]'`

Comment: Hi @Greg , thanks for this real answer to the problem. But I'm using Nuxt 2 which use Webpack 4 and output doesn't seems to be a rules property. So I'm at a lost on how I can fix this to be able to upgrade the Node version (build on Docker). Any idea? Thx!

Comment: I am getting a "Error: Digest method not supported" error when setting `output.hashFunction` to `xxhash64`. Perhaps because I am using Webpack v4?

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer just does not work at all...When you change experiments.futureDeafults to true - webpack throws the error: "experiments is an invalid configuration object, and when setting output hashFunction to xxhash64, you get the error which Paul Razvan Berg mentions above - This answer needs to either be explained further or removed entirely - it caused me more problems than it solved.

Comment: FYI @Claire, Nuxt3 is out and stable (haven't used it yet): https://nuxt.com/v3

Comment: Oddly it did not work for me. I am using symfony 6 web pack encore

Comment: Unfortunately webpack is not the only one that can throw such an error...

Comment: @KristianRoebuck babel-loader, too!

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg et al, I had the same issue, the reason was because my webpack version was outdated. If you can't upgrade your webpack version, you can use a different hash algorithm like `sha256`. I do not know the security implications of choosing such a hash

Comment: @JuliusGoddard I had the same issue, but updated my Webpack5 from "5.28.0" to "5.89.0" and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 85):

**Update April 2023:**

> This answer was first posted in December 2021, it has been over a year so this answer might not as reliable or relevant anymore. See other answers about more causes behind this problem and the most updated solution.

Some top answers did not work.

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

And some top answers were not applicable, modifying `package.json` file:

```json
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
```

This is caused by the latest `node.js V17` compatible issues with `OpenSSL`, see [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40547) and [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532) issue on GitHub.

The easiest thing is just downgrade from `node.js V17` to `node.js V16`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-node-version) on how to downgrade `node.js`.

Comment: Confirming that downgrading version to `V.16` fixed the issue. `nvm install v16 && nvm alias default v16 && nvm use v16` .

Comment: Downgrading from v17 to v16 fixes the issue

Comment: Yes this solution works perfectly. I've V17 in my workstation and facing this issue. Whereas the same `package.json` in my GitHub action uses V16 and this error is not happening. Thanks!

Comment: downgrading isn't a good option

Comment: well, If I add this option, my React code doesn't compile. I get below error ..........Failed to compile
./node_modules/react-idle-timer/dist/index.esm.js
SyntaxError: /Users/abdc/thank-you-cards-new/node_modules/react-idle-timer/dist/index.esm.js: Missing class properties transform.

Answer (score 84):

**For macOS, Windows and Linux**

After updating to [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) version 18.17.1, I got into this issue running on my local host, and I was able to resolve it by updating my start command in the [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) file.

Please find the appropriate command below.

```
"start": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start"
```

You can also use `npm audit fix --force`. This will also fix it, but somehow it didn't work for me.

Comment: Windows users can use `set` instead of `export`, e.g: `"start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start"`

Comment: npm audit fix --force This worked for me. Thanks...!

Comment: I also added that to the build part 
"build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build",

Answer (score 80):

I found the commands below on GitHub:

For Windows, use the below command in cmd:

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

For Unix, use:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But can you explain why this is happening and how this command fixes the problem?

Comment: Worked for me thanks, but this is not a permanent solution.

Comment: @AliKHalili This github link explains it :- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-947012063

Comment: @AbdulBasitRishi Yes, sadly it is not. The easier one would be downgrade the node version. Seems like a new version issue in Node. Probably they will fix it

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [Ajoy Karmakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported/69699772#69699772) (also without any explanation whatsoever).

Comment: Also note that this sets Node to _always be insecure_ so never do this, it's an absolutely terrible idea. Only ever use this flag on a per-run (or per-npm-script) basis.

Comment: This was the correct solution for me. I am not interested in reverting to a version of Node with known security issues. Appreciate it!

Comment: I used it and got this error 'electron: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS' 
Now, I don't know how to undo this lol

Answer (score 60):

It's the Node.js version.

I have this error on Node.js 17, but it's fine when I switch my Node.js version to an older version (16) by using `nvm`.

Comment: Same here. Reverting to node 16 resolved the issue.

Comment: Yup. encountered when trying to run hardhat tests just now. would love to hear a breakdown of what's causing it.

Comment: You were right, rolling the npm version back to 16.13.x worked!

Comment: If you're using the package manager Chocolatey, you can just `choco uninstall nodejs` and `choco install nodejs-lts` to install the LTS version of node.

Comment: Somehow, this error also happens to me on node v16...

Comment: Same issue on Node v18, revert to v16 helped.

Comment: Same here. Dowgraded to node v16 and it's working fine now

Answer (score 47):

**For Vue.js related**

1. Enable the legacy OpenSSL provider.

   On Unix-like systems (Linux, macOS, [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway), etc.):

   ```
   export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
   ```

   On the Windows command prompt:

   ```
   set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
   ```

   On PowerShell:

   ```
   $env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--openssl-legacy-provider"
   ```
2. In [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)

   Reconfigure this script for `npm run serve` as below;

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --openssl-legacy-provider",
    },
   ```

Answer (score 38):

> Failed to construct transformer: Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

The simplest and easiest solution to solve the above error is to downgrade Node.js to v14.18.1. And then just delete folder `node_modules` and try to rebuild your project and your error must be solved.

Comment: this is weirdly worded :|
try using the ` character around code
[markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Version v16.13.0 instead of 17.x worked as well for me. I also didn't need to delete the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: I'm running node version 14.17.3 and I'm still having this issue.

Comment: Sep 22: All github actions are run with Node 16: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/

Comment: Downgrading to Node 14 resolved the issue for me.

Comment: got error on 18.18.0, then switch to node 16.17.0 solved the issue, and remove node modules and rebuild not required

Answer (score 38):

Temporary solution below. Actual solution is upgrading to Webpack 5.

## Updated december 2022

This worked for me (downgrading to Node.js 16):

```
nvm install 16 --lts
nvm use 16
```

Using [Node.js Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) ([for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/nvm-sh/nvm)).

Comment: It worked for me but I had to do `nvm install lts` without the dashes (Windows 10 - Powershell).

Comment: It worked for me, but on my machine `nvm install --lts` already uses the version it installs, so no need to execute `nvm use`

Comment: This would no longer work as LTS is now 18

Comment: need to use like `nvm install 16.15.0` or whatever version you want. then `nvm use 16.15.0`

Comment: Consider the warnings in this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027407/1459653 - answer before doing this.

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading to Webpack 5 resolved this issue for me.

Comment: This worked for me after trying other answers

Answer (score 38):

I had the same error.

My case:

I installed a fresh [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) TypeScript application, added some [SCSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) content and some components.

Locally, my build was working, but when I tried to publish, it was failing with an error:

> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

I fixed this issue by updating my React script library to 5.0.1:

```
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
```

Comment: wawww 2 weeks of work, after unistall npm and update to the current one, actually was like from one problem to another fixing that pop up another again but finally when I update the local frontend, backend's nodejs and npm so does my laptop system nodejs. I change my react-scripts to latest version.it works

Comment: I've just run `yarn add react-scripts`.

Comment: I have gone through all the answers but this one seemed more relevant as I am using current Node LTS v 18. Instead of downgrading Node version or using legacy SSL provider, using the latest react-script library fixed my problem.

Answer (score 33):

To bypass the error (in a development environment) you can simply run

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

before launching your [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) application.

Answer (score 27):

For Angular apps:

You can also edit the `npm start` script in package.json. Instead of

```
"start": "ng serve -o"
```

to

```
"start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && ng serve -o"
```

When you run `npm run start` in the terminal/command line, it will first set the `NODE_OPTIONS` to avoid the problem.

Comment: This was the solution for me to run an Angular 9 app with Node v18.14.0.

Comment: I had pulled down an Angular 12 sample from github and ran into the error.  I have Node v18.17.0.  This solution worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me, running a code base using Angular version 11 with my environment using version 20.11.1

Answer (score 25):

##### Windows

1. Install [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases/download/1.1.11/nvm-setup.exe).
2. Install the Node.js version that you want.

   ```bash
   nvm install 16
   ```
3. Change your Node.js version

   ```bash
   nvm use 16
   ```
4. Check the Node.js versions installed

   ```bash
   nvm list
   ```

#### macOS

Just setting `NODE_OPTIONS` then restart again:

```bash
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75179767/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

This is a common error when packages on a project are not updated and the **React version** that you use is not the latest.

To fix this problem, you need to change your **package.json** file this way:

Change this

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

to this

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Comment: this has already been posted, also it's only appropriate for dev env

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem, and the following worked.

Set the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable to `--openssl-legacy-provider`. To do this, open your terminal and run the below command:

#### For macOS, Linux or Windows [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway)

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Comment: This is working

Answer (score 18):

I faced this issue in Docker build, and I have added this line in the Docker file:

```
RUN export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && yarn build && yarn install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline
```

For local development, add the switch in file *package.json*.

Comment: NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider is command line argument which should be present when you run yarn build. Nothing to do with Docker. 
When you build docker image of your application above line is what you use to build

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of [Ajoy Karmakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported/69699772#69699772). This one is also missing an explanation. Can you please provide an explanation? E.g., why is `--openssl-legacy-provider` necessary? Why all the `yarn` stuff? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69749630/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: The answer above runs in docker file with yarn as package manager. This will help users who are using similar environments and unable to resolve with other answers provided. Ill edit the answer with more explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Running audit fixed the problem for me

```
npm audit fix --force
```

Comment: The uncomfortable path, but the right path. I had to run the audit fix more than once until it completed most fixes. Just minor code brakes. Worth it

Comment: Solved my case on the first try! Thanks for keeping my system secure!.

Answer (score 17):

As a 2022 reader, none of the answers address the fact that this issue was fixed early on for Webpack 5 users (but not backported to Webpack 4). If you're on Webpack 5, simply **upgrade to at least `5.61.0`**. See this comment [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-955682484) on the thread tracking this issue.

Comment: npm install webpack@latest

Comment: Thank you! This answer helped me solve the issue in a reasonable way. It is like the 22nd answer on the page but it is by far the most reasonable. The error is happening inside of webpack. So it makes sense to update webpack. I updated to the latest version of webpack and now I no longer see this error.

The other answers are basically 1. hide the error message 2. upgrade all dependencies or 3. downgrade your dependencies. To be fair, those answers will make the error message go away. But they aren't the best answers.

Comment: @Kevin It blew my mind how hard it was to find that Webpack straight up fixed the issue and you just have to update to get the fix. I was too stubborn to go with any of these hacks.

Comment: I updated webpack to 5.8.0 but issue is still the same...

Comment: @John 5.8.0 is not higher than 5.61.0. 5.80.0 is.

Answer (score 14):

If you are facing this error and you do not want to change your main configuration, an easy fix would be to use the following approach. I am not sure if it is recommended as a good practice, though.

Feel free to correct it.

Initially, let’s say this is the scripts section of my `package.json` file:

```
...
"version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "npm run build:test-app:testing",
    "build:test-app:testing": "ng build test-app --deploy-url  https://test-app.com/ --configuration=test-config",
    ...
  },
  "private": true,
...
```

In order to use this `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` you can do the following:

```
"version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
....
    "build": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider npm run build:test-app:testing”,
    "build:test-app:testing": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider ng build test-app --deploy-url  https://test-app.com/ --configuration=test-config"
...
  },
  "private": true,
```

Take note of the build scripts. I have added an option: `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`

This helps solve this error in Node.js version 17.

For those with the flexibility of changing the build system's Node.js version, just switch to a version lower that 17, e.g., version 16.

For Docker, the use case of using this initially, which always pulls the latest version:

```
...
FROM node:alpine
...
```

You can switch to something like:

```
...
FROM node:16-alpine3.12
...
```

Answer (score 14):

check

```
node -v
v17.4.0
```

then roll back to node --lts (node v16.13.2 (npm v8.1.2)) for that use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script).

```
nvm install 16
```

then check `node -v` and confirm it's version 16.

Comment: I'm using v16.13.2 and I've this error

Comment: This worked for me, also I did update react scripts first so one of them fixed the issue.

Comment: Remember that your answer will outlive what `lts` means. Right now it's v16, a year from now it's going to be v18, so if you're telling folks they need v16, give the nvm instructions for that version, not "whatever lts happens to be".

Comment: Consider the warnings in this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027407/1459653 - answer before doing this.

Answer (score 14):

Same Error with node version **v18.0.0**
and nuxt framework version **2.15** when running dev server and will be fixed by:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider nuxt"
}
```

Comment: Got error: Cannot find module

Answer (score 12):

**This solution worked for me.**

This error is coming in Node.js version 17+, so try to downgrade the Node.js version.

1. Uninstall Node.js from the computer.
2. Download Node.js version 16 and install it again from *https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.0/*

That's all.

Comment: but why? Why did node v17 have problems

Comment: @Evergreen This is most likely a webpack4 issue, also in version 17 Node.js developers have deprecated of trailing slash pattern mappings which is unsupported in the import maps specification. Node.js developers needs to resolve this asap.

Comment: yea, i would expect node js, being such a widely used product, would have a bit more care put into backwards compatibility.

Comment: or, if you're using nvm (node version manager) (and if you're not, you should be, so take this moment to do so...), you can just type `nvm install 16` and you're good to go.

Comment: note that the phrasing is misleading: the "error" is not an error at all, it's Node 17+ actually using an secure, rather than known insecure, version of OpenSSL. The _bypass_ is to install Node 16 and keep running with insecure SSL behaviour, but the _solution_ is to update your dependencies to ones that are Node 17+ compatible.

Answer (score 12):

**This answer is an immediate OpenSSL system-level workaround without touching a previously working build configuration.**

In the ideal world, you have time to upgrade and migrate insecure build dependencies and make sure you didn't break something else in *your* application (or wholesale just avoid webpack, or in my case migrate from [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) to [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) which uses esbuild).

You "should" instead either, (a) [tell webpack to use a newer hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73465262/809572), or (b) mitigate the offending packages with `npm audit`.

---

##### System-level OpenSSL workaround

The quickest workaround is to *temporarily* re-enable MD4 by enabling the "legacy" crypto providers within the system-wide OpenSSL configuration.

**This is incredibly insecure and heavy-handed. Afterwards, you should disable the legacy crypto methods.**

(Unfortunately, the following is only tested to work on Linux).

1. Backup your existing OpenSSL configuration:
   `sudo cp /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.BAK`
2. Append (or uncomment) the following configuration to enable the legacy "providers" (as OpenSSL calls them). You probably want to `sudo vim /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` or similar.

   ```
   [provider_sect]
   default = default_sect
   legacy = legacy_sect

   [default_sect]
   activate = 1

   [legacy_sect]
   activate = 1
   ```
3. Rerun your node script as before.
4. **Disable the legacy providers afterwards**.

   `sudo mv -f /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.BAK /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

This solution is from an [answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73744986/809572).

---

##### What is the underlying cause?

Node uses OpenSSL for its hash functions and encryption on *nix systems. The latest version of OpenSSL disables MD4 by default—**which will break any previously working program that uses MD4**. With that in mind, any npm package that thought using MD4 for file hashes was a "good idea" are now broken—even though MD4 has been [considered broken by RSA Labs since 1996](https://web.archive.org/web/20190928182507/ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pdfs/bulletn4.pdf)! MD4 was also "officially" relegated as obsolete by [RFC 6150](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6150.html) in 2011.

Answer (score 11):

You have to use **MD5** in this file. MD4 is the default, but it will not work.
It will work without an issue, until you delete the [node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder.

Go to this path:
*/node_modules/metro-cache/src/

Change the file *stableHash.js* like below **from md4 to md5**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Hitesh your solution saved me

Comment: This must have many votes. this is the answer finally helped me. btw @hitesh will there be fixes in future from RN

Comment: You're my hero!! From all answers this solution worked :)

Comment: Tis worked for me. Is it not possible to fix this by updating a relevant package though?

Comment: How is this a solution? You are editing a node module which will be replaced on the next install.

Answer (score 7):

In PowerShell:

```
$env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--openssl-legacy-provider"
```

It worked with Node.js v18.7.0.

Comment: I wish I had navigated to page 2 before reading through [the discussion to find this answer](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-1208965919), but hey, a working solution is a solution 

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me in my app expo (downgrading from Node.js 17 to Node.js 12 or 14).

If you have nvm installed you can change the version of node:

First check versions of Node.js in nvm:

```
nvm list
```

Second, install version 12 or 14:

```
nvm install v12.22.8
```

Comment: Downgrading is not a secure and long-term viable solution.

Comment: I am using Node 18, also working on an Expo app. Installing the latest version of @expo/webpack-config and allowing any version of Expo to be installed (use the "*" constraint in package.json), fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

`npm update` fixed it for me. NPM V18

Comment: `yarn upgrade` worked for me as of 8/28/23

Comment: I think you mean Node v18. npm only goes up to v10 at the moment

Answer (score 6):

Add a file called *.npmrc* in the root of the project, and add this to the file:

```
node-options="--openssl-legacy-provider"
```

You can also always remove it easily.

Comment: this one the only one that works for elm on github actions CI, environment variable didn't work

Answer (score 5):

You need to update react-scripts to the latest version

```
npm update react-scripts --save
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. :/

Comment: This didn't work for me, either.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue for a [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js) project. I uninstalled the new version (greater than 18) of Node.js from the machine and installed a previous version (v16.14.2). It works.

Comment: I did the same and it works!

Comment: Yes it works, but is not a solution.

Comment: Yes. It's just like a workaround

Comment: Consider the warnings in this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027407/1459653 - answer before doing this.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error when I was migrating a [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) project to support TypeScript.

1. delete the [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder
2. run the `npm install` command
3. run the `npm audit fix --force` command
4. try to start the server

This worked for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34754819)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick fix that was suggested and worked for me. *[cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command))* into your new *App* directory that you made; you may need to `sudo this install`, and then run the following:

Run:

`npm install -g npm-check-updates`

Then:

`ncu -u`

Then:

`npm install`

Then:

`npm start`

Comment: This is dangerous because it indiscriminately will force all packages to update. For example, one of my apps was written in Vue2, and running the commands listed pushed it to the latest Vue3 release. It would certainly break my app.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this problem on Windows by uninstalling [OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) 1.1.1, installing OpenSSL 3 (if you use [Chocolatey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet#Chocolatey): `choco install openssl.light`) and updating [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)) to the latest version (currently 14), that solves the abovementioned problem with [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) configuration.

Certainly, downgrading Node.js, as most of the answers suggest, is not a proper way to go.

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

On Dockerfile you should add:

```
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Comment: Near duplicate: [Ajoy Karmakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported/69699772#69699772) (also without any explanation whatsoever)

Comment: I wanted it to be clear how to use with Docker

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this error by updating my version of `babel-loader` after updating [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack). However, it may be due to another loader or plugin. `loader-runner` appears in the console output of the original question. See the comment [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-1324340823).

Comment: It is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported/74303582#74303582).

Answer (score 2):

I am getting the same issue with another project. I have cloned it here: *[react-toolkit-example](https://github.com/AaronNGray/react-toolkit-example)*

Issue:

*[error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error #1](https://github.com/AaronNGray/react-toolkit-example/issues/1)*

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

It works as a temporary fix, but I need a proper solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

Only running the below command fixed my issues:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

Answer (score 2):

**After updating node js this happens**

**the best solution for now is just run**

```
npm audit fix --force
```

if did not work
just delete node_modules and package-lock.json
then again try

```
npm install
npm audit fix --force
```

Answer (score 1):

**Go to:**: https://nodejs.org/en/

And download the *recommended* version for most users.

Then uninstall Node.js from your PC and install the *recommended* version.

From what I understand, this is a problem from the developer team. They will fix it ASAP, but in the meantime use the recommended version and everything is going to be OK.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error while using GatsbyJs, all you need to do is downgrade the **node** version to **long-term support**. There is no other salvation

Comment: Sadly that's no help now that the 18 LTS is throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Running react with docker]

This might not be an answer to the question for everyone. But for anyone running node 17 and above in docker, downgrading just as everyone has said will be helpful. No need for the open-legacy-sslprovider. A simple switch in your Dockerfile from using

```
From node
```

to using

```
From node:16.*
```

fixes this issue in docker.

Comment: This worked for me and I'm not using docker. Downgrading to node 16 fixed my problems.

`
nvm use 16
rm -rf node_modules
rm yarn.lock
yarn install
yarn build
`

Comment: I was using Docker, and this fixed it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As simple as it may sound, if it's feasible, **upgrade all your dependencies** in your *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* file to the latest (just type in the name in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?) and use the suggested version). Also use the latest [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version of Node.js.

I had problems before, and even with migrating my project to use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/), I was able to finally solve this problem. There isn't any need to compromise the security with SSL hacks.

Answer (score 1):

Before you change your `npm` version or make any configuration changes, simply run `npm update` to update your packages to the newest minor versions.

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those who don’t want to play around with [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) versions.
The project is an [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) application, with [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) 4.x version.

Some encodings and hash algorithms does not match. I played a few hours to find a matching pair for my Node.js and dependencies I use.

Simply add this Webpack configuration to the output section, hashFunction and hashDigest:

```
output:{
    hashFunction: 'sha256',
    hashDigest: 'base64'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I start a [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) project, try to open [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) and run the command `npm start`. This message is shown:

> " error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"

I just fixed this problem in this way:
Open the terminal in the same project folder and type `npm audit fix --force`

Take some time to install the missing packages and then go to the same project folder terminal and hit `npm start` .
This works perfectly. (I used Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I changed Node.js versions with nvm. If you are using [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) in your project, please try:

`sudo npm rebuild node-sass`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when deploying a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) project to [Vercel](https://github.com/vercel/vercel). I downgraded [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) in file *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* by adding:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "v16.15.0"
},
```

Comment: It helps to mark code/config lines using the tick character around the line so that it stands out from the overall comment.
`"engines": { "node": "v16.1." }`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using an [Azure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure) setup. When I raised a pull request, I got this error. So I just removed some commented code, and again raised a pull request.

This time I didn't see this error. This happens in my case. So whenever I get the error, I do the same thing. It will work for me.

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4329245Z
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4330391Z     at new Hash
 (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4331701Z > prospercare-prospercare-web@0.1.0 build
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4333051Z     at Object.createHash
(node:crypto:133:10)
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4333712Z > GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts
build
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4336913Z     at module.exports
(/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4337284Z
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4338580Z     at NormalModule._initBuildHash
(/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4339132Z Creating an optimized production build...
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4340765Z     at handleParseError
(/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4343721Z     at
/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4345956Z     at
/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4348198Z     at
/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
2023-04-13T13:17:28.4350393Z     at iterateNormalLoaders
(/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/loader-
runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but with my [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) React application, so I just upgrade my babel-loader module, and all the [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) and Webpack modules. These modules are upgraded and are compatible with [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) > V17. I recommend to upgrade your packages which are affected by this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Running [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) v20.6.1, [Debian 11.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_11_(Bullseye)) (Bullseye), [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) 20.10.21, and hitting this problem, I just used `npm audit fix --force` and it resolved.

I am not using nvm.  I noticed that `npm audit fix --force` did upgrade react-scripts to 5.0.1.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue with Node.js 17.0.1. I solved it by following these steps:

- Open *Control Panel* → *Program and Features* → *Node.js* and uninstall Node.js by right-clicking a
- Go to website *https://nodejs.org/en/* and download the version and install.

Comment: Re *"Control Panel → Program and Features"*: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably?

Answer (score -1):

I came across this issue today and resolved it by switching Node.js versions using "nvm".

I've been working on a couple of personal projects using Node.js, Next.js [1](https://nextjs.org/), and React [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)). What often happens to me is that I don't remember exactly which version of Node.js I use for which project.

And so, usually, I would try to use Node.js 16 for a project that is currently using Node.js 14.

I haven't figured out a better way to remember the version of Node.js for each project, so I usually just save all the commands that I need to run to get the application started in readme.MD.

Answer (score -1):

In **Angular.io** projects, the accepted (unsupported) version of **Nodes.js** is **v16.x.x**.

In **Nodes v17.x** version, the same error described in this question occurs.

**Solution:**

**Uninstall nodes** and reinstall version v16.x  (for Windows).

Comment: my development environment: 
- Angular CLI: 12.2.1
- Node: 16.14.0 (Unsupported)
- Package Manager: npm 7.5.6
- OS: win32 x64

Answer (score -1):

I fixed by using the LTS version:

```bash
echo "lts" > .nvmrc
nvm install
```

React Native has a buggy script to find the path of the Node.js executable.

This sets the version to the latest stable version of Node.js through [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

What I found is that even if Node.js is in my path, if I have an ~/.nvm directory it's going to try to find use in nvm and fail. This sets the current node to be linked to the one in ~/.nvm and thus that React Native can find.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue because of [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Linux).

I downgraded to [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) v16, but without any luck.

The problem was that Fedora installs Node.js v18 when installing [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/).

So you have to uninstall the preinstalled Node.js using:

```
sudo dnf remove nodejs
```

Then install Node.js using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm):

```
nvm install 16.19.1
```

Then install Yarn using **npm**, not [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNF_(software)):

```
sudo npm install yarn -g
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this error trying to 'yarn build' and I'm using Node.js v18.17.1.

This was my *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* file...

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "env-cmd -f ../../dotenv/.env.production webpack --mode production
...
}
...
```

My *webpack.config.js* is as follows and I'm trying to run ^ `webpack --mode production`, but mode in my *webpack.config.js* is development:

```
module.exports = {
   mode: "development",
   entry: './app/App.js',
   output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '/build/'),
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'assets/bundle.js'
   },
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this in my angular project, downgrading node was the answer but not the complete answer, after downgrading node, npm started failing, so I had to upgrade node again, then uninstall npm and then install the older node version so it installed the npm compatible with the older node version. Then ng started failing so I had to uninstall angular cli and install the compatible cli.

This matrix helped:
https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
npm create react-app --template typescript foo --use-npm
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What does it do? How does it work? Why does it work? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69791488/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -3):

Switching to a different version of Node.js also works. In my case, I switched from v19.2.0 to v15.14.0.

Answer (score -3):

So, everyone is suggesting is either to downgrading the version (which in my opinion is not a solution) or add `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` which is also not a solution. I am using [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) version 20 and all I did was to update the npm.

Just run

```
npm update
```

Then run the application again. I faced this issue in an [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) project when images were not being loaded. It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score -4):

Downgrade your Node.js version to 16.19.1.

Node.js 16.19.1

This fixes my problem.

Comment: Upvoted. Also works for me. I think this answer is useful; using Node 16 (although v18+ are the currently stable releases) is a viable solution if someone just wants to use Node as a static site generator that works in an isolated CI/CD environment (e.g. nodejs + vuepress).

Comment: right, if I'm just trying to get NPM to run and build output JS files... then upload those JS files somewhere else... how bad could it be to use an older Node version?