# 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED

Tags: create-react-app

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
throw e;
^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\Masum PC\ami-parbona\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss\package.json
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:416:9)
at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:669:3)
at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\Masum PC\ami-parbona\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\lib\safe-parser.js:1:17) {
code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.0.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69706112/16223122) in [Error ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in the package.json of a module in node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693907/error-err-package-path-not-exported-package-subpath-lib-tokenize-is-not-d) Also see the "workaround" in the comment

Answer (score 6):

While doing on my nextJs project -

> npm run dev

I found the same error. I have solved this by doing some steps.

> 1. Created a new project on other folder using `npx create-next-app@latest` (or for react project use the respective command to create a new project)
> 2. In My current project where I'm getting the error I deleted the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file (not the package.json file)
> 3. Opened the package.json file of current project and replaced the `next ,react, react-dom` version with latest project's version which I have created on other folder.
> 4. Now simply `npm install` and then run the project

**Explanation**:- This error normally occur if you trying to run a old project where versions are different than your current installed version. So you need to use exact version on package.json file as current installed version.
If you exactly know the versions then no need to create a new project , just replace the version.

While searching for the solution over stackoverflow I found that `npm update` command worked well for others because that answer was upvoted. But for me (using ubuntu 20) this wasn't working so I need to manually update the version of package.json.

[image: This screenshot]

You can see the screenshot which refer the where to replace the new version.

You might have other packages inside the dependencies , you might need to upgrade the latest version of other packages as well.

In my react-native project, I have to upgrade the `react-native-camera` version to run the application on my new system but it was running well on my old system.

So the conclusion is `**UPGRADE THE VERSION(S)**`.

Answer (score 6):

I totally agree with [TripleM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73259208/9535043) (please refer to that answer for more details) but I'm going to suggest a short and sweet answer here.

First, uninstall these 3 npm packages: (next, react, react-dom)

```
npm uninstall next react react-dom
```

Then, reinstall them with the latest versions

```
npm install --save next react react-dom
```

If this method is not working for you try [TripleM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73259208/9535043), that might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I git clone'd [this](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/workshops) repo.

What worked was downgrading my node.js version from current to lts. I used `nvm use --lts`.

Answer (score 1):

add --openssl-legacy-provider to the package.json where scripts
It should turn out like this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Posting here as I had a different cause.

For me, I was using AWS Amplify, which uses AWS CodeBuild behind the scenes.

I had modified some of my dependencies, devDependencies, and peerDependencies for multiple packages in a monorepo.

The build failed because my web app was trying to pull in an old version of the `entities` library, way down in the dependency tree.

```
$ pnpm why entities
html-react-parser 3.0.9
└─┬ html-dom-parser 3.1.3
  └─┬ htmlparser2 8.0.1
    ├─┬ domutils 3.0.1
    │ └─┬ dom-serializer 2.0.0
    │   └── entities 2.2.0
    └── entities 2.2.0
```

Resulting in this CI/CD build error:

```
2023-02-22T05:39:28.319Z [INFO]: @myapp/webapp:build: cache miss, executing cd449f2fbd550ffc
2023-02-22T05:39:28.775Z [INFO]: @myapp/webapp:build:
                                 @myapp/webapp:build: > @myapp/webapp@0.1.0 build /codebuild/output/src711556549/src/myapp/apps/webapp
                                 @myapp/webapp:build: > react-scripts build
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:
2023-02-22T05:39:28.952Z [INFO]: @myapp/webapp:build: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:560
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:       throw e;
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:       ^
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:
                                 @myapp/webapp:build: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/decode_codepoint' is not defined by "exports" in /codebuild/output/src711556549/src/myapp/node_modules/.pnpm/node_modules/entities/package.json
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:     at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:365:9)
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:     at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:649:3)
2023-02-22T05:39:28.953Z [INFO]: @myapp/webapp:build:     at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:554:36)
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:     at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:594:31)
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1007:27)
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:866:27)
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093:19)
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:     at Object.<anonymous> (/codebuild/output/src711556549/src/myapp/node_modules/.pnpm/node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/Tokenizer.js:6:42) {
                                 @myapp/webapp:build:   code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
                                 @myapp/webapp:build: }
2023-02-22T05:39:28.957Z [INFO]: @myapp/webapp:build:  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
2023-02-22T05:39:28.962Z [WARNING]: @myapp/webapp:build: ERROR: command finished with error: command (/codebuild/output/src711556549/src/myapp/apps/webapp) pnpm run build exited (1)
2023-02-22T05:39:28.962Z [WARNING]: command (/codebuild/output/src711556549/src/myapp/apps/webapp) pnpm run build exited (1)
                                    ERROR  run failed: command  exited (1)
```

It took me a while to realize that, in my build settings, the build was caching node_modules:

```
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
```

The solution, I just needed to comment the about build settings line, kick off another build, then un-comment.

```
      cache:
        paths:
          # - node_modules/**/*
```

After the build succeeded, I restored this caching of the node_modules so that future CI/CD builds would be potentially faster.

The correct dependency tree:

```
$ pnpm why entities 
html-react-parser 3.0.9
└─┬ html-dom-parser 3.1.3
  └─┬ htmlparser2 8.0.1
    ├─┬ domutils 3.0.1
    │ └─┬ dom-serializer 2.0.0
    │   └── entities 4.4.0
    └── entities 4.4.0
```

See build setting info here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html#yml-specification-syntax

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and as mentioned above the solution is to execute inside the same project, where you run the install command:

```
npm install
npm update
```

Answer (score 0):

I got such error when tried to run a React app which was created using Node v16 but I had Node v18 installed. What helped me: I removed Node v18 and installed Node v16