# How can I fix a a npm/yarn start issue?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, npm, yarnpkg

```
    yarn run v1.22.10
$ react-scripts start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in /home/victor/Desktop/epitech/tek3/project/B-DEV-500-NCE-5-1-dashboard-victor.sorais/epiboard/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:429:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:683:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/victor/Desktop/epitech/tek3/project/B-DEV-500-NCE-5-1-dashboard-victor.sorais/epiboard/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parser.js:1:17) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

I created a react app with `npx-create-app <app_name>`, but i don't understand what is the problem, I've already updated all my package, tested rm all webpack package and `npm install` and more other option. Any idea ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582 throw err](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800/internal-modules-cjs-loader-js582-throw-err)

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily fix this issue by downgrading the node version to `16.13.0`. If you are running it on mac you can install `nodeV16`.

```
brew install node@16
```

It seems a lot of people are facing these issues with the latest node version. I am attaching some links which might help you resolve this ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693907/error-err-package-path-not-exported-package-subpath-lib-tokenize-is-not-d) and [link2](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11579)) if above thing doesn't work.

Note: remove the existing version and install a new fresh one. You can check [this](https://reactgo.com/uninstall-node-npm-from-windows/) link to remove it completely(I am not writing same commands with description as a lot people already explained it)

Comment: You can mark it as accepted for future references.