# Yarn start not working for react js after tried setting react native environment mac m1

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, apple-m1

```
ajayror@Ajays-MacBook-Air phgh % yarn start
yarn run v1.22.11
warning ../../package.json: No license field
$ react-scripts start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/ajayror/Desktop/phgh/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:416:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:669:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ajayror/Desktop/phgh/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parser.js:1:17) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.0.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693907/error-err-package-path-not-exported-package-subpath-lib-tokenize-is-not-d
There is an accepted solution, yuou should try it and/or the other suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like we all are facing the same issue, it's taken me so long to solve this problem. Simply follow this, **uninstall** the current version of node **(v17.0.1)** and **install** **LTS(v16.13.1)**. I hope it will work no matter what.

Thanks for your douth.