# Issue with running npm start. Weird error

Tags: reactjs

I am having issues with getting npm run to start

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports"
```

Here is the package.json

```
"name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

any help would be awesome!

Comment: Please refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693907/error-err-package-path-not-exported-package-subpath-lib-tokenize-is-not-d

Comment: Also try to search the question before asking it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error \[ERR\_PACKAGE\_PATH\_NOT\_EXPORTED\]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in the package.json of a module in node\_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693907/error-err-package-path-not-exported-package-subpath-lib-tokenize-is-not-d)

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when using the latest version of Node. Try rolling back to the LTS version `16.13.0`.

Step 1:

```
nvm uninstall <version>
```

Step 2:

```
nvm install --lts
```

This should work for Windows

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to downgrade the node version here is solution

## Solution 1: Downgrade nodejs version

In my case I am using nodejs v17.0.1 and I am facing above error. So that I just downgrade my nodejs to LTS version My error solved automatically. To downgrade nodejs Just use this command. First of all just uninstall latest version. Use this command.

```
nvm uninstall v17.0.1

          OR

nvm uninstall <your version>
```

and then Install LTS version. Use this command.

```
nvm install --lts
```

## Solution 2: Delete node_modules and reinstall

Just delete node_modules and and .lock file then re-install your packages. And again run npm start and now your error might be solved.