# I am getting an error when I am running this project in VS CODE

Tags: node.js

```
PS C:\Users\gaveshanapraveen\Downloads\react-based-online-escape-game-main\react-based-online-escape-game-main> npm start

> digital-event-2021-main-app@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:544
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\gaveshanapraveen\Downloads\react-based-online-escape-game-main\react-based-online-escape-game-main\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss\package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:361:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:697:9)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:538:36)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:607:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:893:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gaveshanapraveen\Downloads\react-based-online-escape-game-main\react-based-online-escape-game-main\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\lib\safe-parser.js:1:17) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

Node.js v18.14.0

Please can anyone help me with this problem

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69693907/2158271) about the actual problem and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44700432/2158271) how to change Node version in VSCode.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.