# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported [ANGULAR]

Tags: angular, jenkins, npm, node-modules, primeng

I was trying to build my project on jenkins. The local build is successful but Jenkins build is failing. Any fix for this?
I am using primeng module to implement p-organisationchart. I suspect that could be the issue.

versions I am using are:

```
`"primeicons": "^4.1.0",
 "primeng": "^11.3.0",
 "node" : 14.16.0`
```

I am working on Angular 8

Comment: This seems related to NodeJS and webpack, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported

Comment: Can you add more details about why is failing? Any error log would be helpful.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest angular CLI version

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is a webpack issue. As a workaround you can add an environment variable to your build task:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

See [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532) issue in the webpack project.

You can add the environment variable to your package.json scripts part

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider; ng build"
  }
}
```

If you are using docker you can add the environment variable to your Docker file before the build

```
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

I am not familiar with jenkins. If you use bash-like scripts there to build your application you can also add the line to that script.

Note: In windows use set instead of export

---

As mentioned in the comments this solution shouldn't be used for solving this error in production environments as it is deactivating a security fix in ssl.

But for a build pipeline (which was the problem domain in this case) it is still a viable solution in my opinion.

Comment: If this is the "workaround", what is the actual long-term solution?  What do I need to change in my angular project to support Node 17, 18, etc. going forward?

Comment: I also had to add it to the `npm start` script, and then it worked :)

Comment: **Warning:** This is actually caused by an SSL security issue and adding these flags as suggested in the answer will only suppress the warning and not resolve the underlying issue. See also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported#comment123227549_69713899) at a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported#comment123227549_69713899)

Answer (score 16):

I was having this very same error, and it was solved by downgrading from Node 17.2 to 16.10

You may also run this in the console before launching `ng serve`

```sh
$ export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: Using an earlier version of node did it for me, thanks

Comment: This works for me because my computer uses a newer version of Node, while my Angular project uses an older version of Node.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using windows run the following in your terminal and then rebuild the application

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

and for Mac use:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

For more information see [How to Solve “digital envelope routines unsupported” or ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED error when running Angular application](https://howtojs.io/how-to-solve-digital-envelope-routines-unsupported-or-err_ossl_evp_unsupported-error-when-running-angular-application/) .

Comment: It was not working for me on Windows with `Node.js v18.18`. I was still getting the same error even after launching the `set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` command. I finally solved using this script `"build-legacy": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && ng build"`.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer and workaround overlooks security vulnerabilities in older  Node.js version 17, which uses OpenSSL version 3 by default. My organization is requiring upgrade to version 18 of Node.js because of this issue, so to downgrade my version or use legacy OpenSSL is not an option for me.

From below stack trace you can see MD4 hash vulnerability and error and that it occurs in Webpack. So you would think the latest version of Webpack would fix issue.

```
     Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\workspace\ssdweb\src\main\angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\workspace\ssdweb\src\main\angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\workspace\ssdweb\src\main\angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\workspace\ssdweb\src\main\angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\workspace\ssdweb\src\main\angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\workspace\ssdweb\src\main\angular\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\workspace\ssdweb\src\main\angular\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\workspace\ssdweb\src\main\angular\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at C:\workspace\ssdweb\src\main\angular\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at context.callback (C:\workspace\ssdweb\src\main\angular\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.loader (C:\workspace\ssdweb\src\main\angular\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:183:3) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

Comment: Did you get your issue resolved?

Comment: No, not at this time. I thought an install of latest version of webpack would fix it but have too many dependency issues. Went back to older version. Will have to address it in a few weeks, and will try to give update with solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had node version 20 and still having this issue then I removed Angular CLI and installed the latest version and so the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

How to solve the digital envelope routines::unsupported in angular

***Step to Procedure:***

1.Install the old veriosn of node js .
Example 16,17.
My suggestion to use node js 16 version

2.After install the node js check the version in cmd command node -v.

3.After the checking the version build your Project by using ng build --prod command

***Cause of the issue:***

update node js version is not supported in older angular version

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was downgrading to node version 14. Everything else I tried was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem: but all set with the command
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBfC4.png)

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error when this was written. My previous node version was the **latest** (18).
What I do to solve this:

1. go to nodejs website: **nodejs.org**
2. search for version of nodejs which has **npm version 6.14.8** -> I got nodejs v.14.15.0 -> download
3. **extract** your download of nodejs:
   **tar -xf (the-nodejs-file)**
4. edit .bashrc file
   **$ vim ~/.bashrc** and save it by **:wq**
5. add this line:
   **export PATH="/home/(your-name)/Downloads/node-v14.15.0-linux-x64/bin:$PATH"**
6. **restart** your terminal
7. go to your project directory
   **cd (your directory)**
8. run project
   **ng serve**

[image: ng serve works!]