# Error While trying to Compile Angular Application in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

This is the error which occurs when I try to run ng serve --open for my app, And it also shows error while ng --version to check version it shows node 17 is not supported with this angular, but when I try to run another app that works but which I downloaded doesn't.

```
/ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...node:internal/crypto/hash:67
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (D:\Training\Angular\mCart\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:145:18)
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (D:\Training\Angular\mCart\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:46:50)
    at RawSource.updateHash (D:\Training\Angular\mCart\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\RawSource.js:77:8)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\Training\Angular\mCart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:880:17)
    at handleParseResult (D:\Training\Angular\mCart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:946:10)
    at D:\Training\Angular\mCart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:1040:4
    at processResult (D:\Training\Angular\mCart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:755:11)
    at D:\Training\Angular\mCart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:819:5 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Comment: You can follow this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69750769/error-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported-angular . There is also a github issue for node 17 https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-947012063

Comment: @AlimurRaziRana, I just tried everything uninstalling and installing update angular and node but at last this occurs, For one project not for new project as i downloaded this project

Answer (score 2):

It is node latest version support issue, I was facing the same issue, I uninstalled the version from my system and downloaded a downgraded version from the official node website

https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

I installed Node.js 16.19.1 and i was able to run ng serve

Comment: How are you using CLI with that version??

Answer (score 1):

You could be running with the latest version of Node, which is not officially supported by Angular, yet. https://angular.io/guide/setup-local#prerequisites

Install the LTS version of Node instead and try again => https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is your node version. Considering downgrading your node version. One way to do it is installing NVM (this [article](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-use-node-version-manager-nvm/) can help)

With NVM you can move between node versions for different projects.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using :

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```