# What is --openssl-legacy-provider in Node.js v17?

Tags: javascript, node.js, openssl

I was building a simple React app using Tailwind. I used `create-react-app` and then installed tailwind. I have done this many times before.

In order to install Tailwind, I also had to install `craco` and change **package.json** "scripts" to use `craco`, like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

However, this time, when I ran `npm start`, I got an error that I had never encountered before:

> `Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported`

So I searched on **StackOverflow** and someone suggested adding `--openssl-legacy-provider` to my "start" script like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "craco --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

And it's working now. But can somebody please explain to me what `--openssl-legacy-provider` actually is and how it works?

Comment: See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-947807590

Comment: But why did it happen this time only and not usually? Do I have to do the same for all my projects in future?

Comment: _"But why did it happen this time only and not usually?"_ Because some module uses commands that aren't supported anymore. _"Do I have to do the same for all my projects in future?"_ Only when you use modules that use unsupported commands. I don't know why this commands aren't supported anymore and if it is related to security but using unsupported commands should be a red flag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Answer (score 9):

I have seen many answers regarding the OpenSSL issue that people encounter due to the changes on Node.js v17. Personally, I encountered the problem in a vue.js/electron application after switching to my new MacBook with M1 chip.

This GitHub issue lists multiple options that worked for different users.
In my scenario, adjusting the script commands in the package.json file worked:

```
"serve": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service serve",

"build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service build"
```

I've seen users replacing the export with a run command.
Keep in mind that the syntax might differ on another Os. For example:

```
Set and set
```

[The full issue with all possible answers.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6770)

Answer (score 6):

Due to changes on **Node.js v17**, `--openssl-legacy-provider` was added for handling key size on **OpenSSL v3**.
You somehow have installed the latest version of node.

1. Restore your previous version of nodejs.
2. Go and manually remove the node dependency(e.g. "node":17.4.3) from package.json
   and packagelock.json.
3. Delete node_modules folder and use `npm install` to reinstall node_modules.

Comment: is there a way to keep node v17+ and still run it?

Comment: Oh no! yet another "downgrade-to-solve-everything" answer... As a Java developer I LOVE Node.JS ... reminds me Java back to 90's. Dependency nightmare. Solution: keep yourself 10 versions behind.

Answer (score 6):

I had this error in Nuxt 2.15
I fixed the error in the following way.

`package.json` edit

I had Ubuntu so this method worked for me

```
"scripts":{
    "dev":"export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && nuxt",
    "build":"export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && nuxt build",
    "start":"export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && nuxt start",
    "generate":"export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && nuxt generate"
  },
```

My partner had Windows but the above method didn't work on it, then this method worked

```
"scripts":{
    "dev":"SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && nuxt",
    "build":"SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && nuxt build",
    "start":"SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && nuxt start",
    "generate":"SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && nuxt generate"
  },
```

The most interesting thing was that it worked in other ways in Ubuntu and Windows

Comment: `export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` sets two different environment variables, `SET` and `NODE_OPTIONS`. These snippets look like cargo cult programming. Don't do this.

Comment: thanks from @Akbarali. I change my package.json script segment in angular   "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "SET NODE_OPTIONS= --openssl-legacy-provider  && ng serve ",
    "build": "SET NODE_OPTIONS= --openssl-legacy-provider  && ng build"
  },

Answer (score 3):

Adding `--openssl-legacy-provider` in `package.json` sure works, but if you don't want to use the legacy SSL provider, you can upgrade your webpack- and react-scripts versions.

I had to first delete *package_lock.json* and *node_modules/*. Then I ran:

```bash
npm install --save-dev webpack@5.74.0 --legacy-peer-deps
npm install --save-dev react-scripts@5.0.1 --legacy-peer-deps
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

After this, I tested with:

```bash
npm start
```

I also had to fix a few other issues, but eventually got it working.

**Edit:**
I eventually found out that updating `react-scripts` made "hot reloading" stop working in my project. My backend is a `ASP.NET Core 3.1` project which uses a .NET Core 3.1 version of `Microsoft.SpaProxy`. This version of `SpaProxy` seems to be incompatible with the latest `react-scripts` version. I eventually reverted to an older `react-scripts` version and added `--openssl-legacy-provider` to the startup command in `package.json` (as have been suggested here already). Now hot reloading works again. The other option would be to move my backend project to `.NET Core 5` (or higher) to make hot reloading work again with the latest `react-scripts` version.

Comment: I'm assuming these other issues were issues relating to polyfills. Would you happen to recall how you solved those and if there was an issue displaying images after doing so?

Comment: Hi, @BasiliskHill. I'm sorry, but my issues were not related to polyfills. I had to modify some files in the Semantic UI npm package.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template/issues/336#issuecomment-983526097)
and it works for my case.

For Node.js v17+, you need to put the `openssl-legacy-provider` flag after your command, for example:

- From `npm --openssl-legacy-provider start` to `npm start --openssl-legacy-provider start`
- From `npm --openssl-legacy-provider build` to `npm start --openssl-legacy-provider build`

... and so on.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Sorry for the inconvenience, this is the first time I post an answer here. Thanks for your advice! I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with Angular, where I had following versions:

```
node -v   => v18.16.1
npm -v    => 9.5.1
```

The solution I figured out is to update the script in **Package.json** as follows:

1. run: `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`
2. Update:`"start": "ng serve"` to `"start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && ng serve"`

Answer (score 1):

From the following code

```
"dev": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && next dev",
"build": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && next build",
"start": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && next -- 
openssl-legacy-provider start",
"lint": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && next lint"
```

I removed the export, it will look like this:

```
"dev": "SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && next dev",
"build": " SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && next build",
"start": " SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && next --openssl- 
 legacy-provider start",
"lint": "SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && next lint"
```

and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using Node v18.18.2 and adding "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider" to the start script

```
"scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
```

solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in on this late in the game so to speak.  But I can vouch that if you do this correctly, you don't have to put the --openssl-legacy-provider in your npm start.

My use case is a ReactJS 17.x SPA with ASP.NET 8.x.  I had actually created the application in the past and just upgraded it through time.  What caused the error was that I got a new computer at work and a much more recent version of Node 20.x.

I too was getting the same error and not able to start npm, so I gave in and used the --openssl-legacy-provider.

So I went ahead and ran npm audit and first first fixed the non-breaking changes, sometimes individually, but finally with npm audit fix.

Then I decided to go for it and ran npm audit fix -f, knowing that non-breaking changes could well, break my app.  The big jump was going from react-scripts 4.0 to 5.0.

I retested the app and to my surprise, everything was working.  I was then able to take out the --openssl-legacy-provider in package.json

```
scripts": {
"prestart": "node aspnetcore-https && node aspnetcore-react",
"start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
```

So I would recommend doing it in the same fashion.  For .NET Core Apps, make sure you have 6.0 or better.  I've heard the prior versions may not support the new react-scripts well.

The best news is that I have a clean report when I do npm audit.  Before I had over 100 vulnerabilities, 19 severe and 9 critical.

If you care about supply chain security, you'll love a clean npm audit.  Yes, I do realize it's not the be all end all of package manager security.

The last note I would add is that I recommend testing often throughout this fix phase.  At first, things were going a bit slowly as I just updated individual packages then retested, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Me sirvio para node v18

```
(set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider) -and (npm run start)
```

ó

```
($env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--openssl-legacy-provider") -and (npm run start)
```

Suerte.

Answer (score -2):

OpenSSL legacy provider is a kind of support for algorithms that have been deprecated or are no longer maintained but have been tagged as legacy.

So, your nodejs application can support some deprecated dependencies used by your Create React App- which is no longer maintained.