# Can Capacitorjs run a native app with NODE_OPTIONS --openssl-legacy-provider

Tags: reactjs, node.js, openssl, capacitor

There is a Reactjs app to convert to native using Capacitor. The app is was originally built in Reactjs 14. We are using Capacitor to build the native version. In order to run the app with Reactjs for the web with the Node 16+ - Node 16+ is a requirement for Capacitorjs - we have to set the environment variable NODE_OPTIONS --openssl-legacy-provider as described here [stackoverflow openssl fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69962209/what-is-openssl-legacy-provider-in-node-js-v17).

Capacitorjs won't run the app while it is still using Reactjs 14 and Node 16 and the NODE_OPTIONS openssl fix. We have a ton of dependencies to update and would like to be able to use the openssl-legacy-provider workaround with Capacitor.

We have tested with a smaller app with no dependencies by updating the React Version to 18 and Node to the most recent version and capacitor ran fine. When building the app we want to upgrade with capacitor it builds and opens the capacitor screen on the mobile device, but the capacitor screen is blank. I have tried using the command line to enter the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable with the set command and entering it in the package.json file with the export command.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.