# React-native error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I am constantly getting the ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED error, I did some research on the internet, I did what was said, but the error did not get fixed, what could be the reason? json.package is as follows.

```
{


"name": "intelijReactNative",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.16.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.16.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

the error is as below

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at stableHash (C:\Users\furka\Desktop\intelijReactNative\node_modules\metro-cache\src\stableHash.js:19:8)
    at Object.getCacheKey (C:\Users\furka\Desktop\intelijReactNative\node_modules\metro-transform-worker\src\index.js:593:7)
    at getTransformCacheKey (C:\Users\furka\Desktop\intelijReactNative\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\getTransformCacheKey.js:24:19)
    at new Transformer (C:\Users\furka\Desktop\intelijReactNative\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:48:9)
    at C:\Users\furka\Desktop\intelijReactNative\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:22:29
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:497:9) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11562 has the details, why to downgrade NodeJs to v16.13.0

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error. If you are using Node version 17+, It isn't compatible with some webpack stuff yet.
Use the LTS version instead. At v16.13.0

Comment: @Ellon I have issuen when running this code
`npx react-native run-android --variant=release`
got error even I downgraded from 16.14.0 to 16.13.0

Answer (score 0):

Remove `--openssl-legacy-provider` from script and downgrade your node version to 16

If you use `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` you can use `unset NODE_OPTIONS` in terminal

If you set that export with `fish` first check to see that with `printenv | grep NODE_OPTIONS` and if you see `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` now you can use `set -e NODE_OPTIONS` for unset from fish

If you can not downgrade node version because you may have used version `17+` in a project, then use [n package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) and install version `16 of Node` and switch between the required versions of Node during the development of each project using this package.

Also, it would be nice to use `sudo` while using `npm n` on macOS or Linux