# How to run start React Error0308010C

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I test create react, but my rum Error:0308010C

```
$npx create-react-app my
$cd my
$npm start
```

[image]

```
> my@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.56.1/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
    at C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
    at C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\Users\yangjiaxiang\Desktop\my\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Node.js v17.0.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help. Add these scripts in file.package.json

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
}
```