# Yarn start not working | error `ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

I have been trying to make this React App, but when I try to do `yarn start` it shows the following error message:

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-scripts start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in /home/abhishek/Documents/Code/weather-react/weather-react/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:429:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:683:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/abhishek/Documents/Code/weather-react/weather-react/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parser.js:1:17) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.2.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How do I fix this?

This is what it shows now:

```
Starting the development server...

/home/abhishek/Documents/Code/weather-react/weather-react/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/home/abhishek/Documents/Code/weather-react/weather-react/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/abhishek/Documents/Code/weather-react/weather-react/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at /home/abhishek/Documents/Code/weather-react/weather-react/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at /home/abhishek/Documents/Code/weather-react/weather-react/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at /home/abhishek/Documents/Code/weather-react/weather-react/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/abhishek/Documents/Code/weather-react/weather-react/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/home/abhishek/Documents/Code/weather-react/weather-react/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /home/abhishek/Documents/Code/weather-react/weather-react/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.2.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. removed /node_modules and yarn.lock file.
   2.then reinstalled deleted packages/file using yarn install .

Comment: Wow okay it worked! But now it shows `localhost refused to connect` and showed this error code: https://pastebin.com/35PLteDt

Comment: link is not working

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eaX9vJx7 is it working now?

Comment: This site can’t provide a secure connectionpastebin.com sent an invalid response.

Comment: oh, I will just edit the post and add it

Comment: ask new question and share link here

Comment: This error is coming in Node.js version 17+, so try to downgrade the Node.js version. or apply this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/70253732/10079978

Comment: so I downgraded to 16.13.1, tried `yarn start` and it said to download cmdtest, so I downloaded and, it still didnt work :(

Comment: okay so I removed cmdtest

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! Downgraded to node 16.13.1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did!

1. Deleted 'node modules' folder & 'yarn.lock'
2. In 'package.json' , added these

   "start": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
   "build": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build"
3. yarn install
4. yarn start