# Error "digital envelope routines::unsupported"

Tags: openssl

I've tried the CMD 'set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider' on Windows from the this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported), but now it wrecked my whole dev enviroment and getting this error on a yarn dev or yarn build:
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

Also downgraded to node v16, but still getting the same error.
Please help **how to UNSET** this:  set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider.

Comment: Try calling `set NODE_OPTIONS=` with nothing after the equal sign (=), that should unset the option.

Comment: check this solution for the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/71033803/11718792