# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported - Next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, node-modules

This problem occurs in the Next.js project with Node version 17 I tried a lot of solutions but this solution is the best you can solve this problem if it occurred with you

```
> landing-page@0.0.1 dev
> next dev

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
ready - started server on http://localhost:3000
node:internal/crypto/hash:67
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (E:\Collage\COURSES\react.js projects2\01.Build and Deploy a Premium Next JS React Website _ Landing Page, Business Website, Portfolio\nextjs_landing_page\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (E:\Collage\COURSES\react.js projects2\01.Build and Deploy a Premium Next JS React Website _ Landing 
Page, Business Website, Portfolio\nextjs_landing_page\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (E:\Collage\COURSES\react.js projects2\01.Build and Deploy a Premium Next JS React Website _ Landing Page, Business Website, Portfolio\nextjs_landing_page\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at E:\Collage\COURSES\react.js projects2\01.Build and Deploy a Premium Next JS React Website _ Landing Page, Business Website, Portfolio\nextjs_landing_page\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at E:\Collage\COURSES\react.js projects2\01.Build and Deploy a Premium Next JS React Website _ Landing Page, Business Website, Portfolio\nextjs_landing_page\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at E:\Collage\COURSES\react.js projects2\01.Build and Deploy a Premium Next JS React Website _ Landing Page, Business Website, Portfolio\nextjs_landing_page\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (E:\Collage\COURSES\react.js projects2\01.Build and Deploy a Premium Next JS React Website _ Landing Page, B    at Array.<anonymous> (E:\Collage\COURSES\react.js projects2\01.Build and Deploy a Premium Next JS React Website _ Landing Page, Business Website, Portfolio\nextjs_landing_page\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
Node.js v17.2.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Comment: No, you can check my answer below
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71033803/11718792

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, install  `cross-env`

```
npx install cross-env
```

then, Just set this in scripts in package.json

```
"dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider' next dev",
```

Last run this command

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: Additional reference here: https://itsmycode.com/error-digital-envelope-routines-unsupported/

Comment: For me it was: 
npm install cross-env. 
npx has not worked

Comment: cross-env is not crucial here, you just need to have environment variable NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider' set, wh
ich you can do simply by running command 
export NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider'

there is alot of ways this can be set automatically, per project or per environment, per user, bash profile etc... but it's not necessary