# electron: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, cross-env

I want create electron app with vue js but I can't start :
I execute this code for run my app :
`"cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider' vue-cli-service electron:serve"`

Return an error : electron: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

I have tried to change node version (18.2.1 / 18.2.0 / 19.2.0 / 17.9.1) It's same

More information :

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "electron": "^13.0.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.1.1"
  },
```

Comment: You should remove that env. variable `NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider'` and try again

Comment: If I don't use Node options I have an other error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71033802/error-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported-next-js/71033803#71033803

Comment: Hello @Arnaud, did you manage to fix it? I am also running into same problem.

Comment: We're suffering from the intersection of Mac M-series chips lacking support for the new openssl options used by node, and electron objecting to forcing node into the older openssl configuration. Downgrading versions is sidestepping the security reasons for Node and Electron's transitions. Long-term we need to configure the Mac to run a sufficient version of openssl.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to remove usages of `--openssl-legacy-provider` wherever Electron might see it. However, webpack then demanded it, otherwise creating an error message `error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported`.

So make sure that any Node scripts that webpack uses includes `node --openssl-legacy-provider` and it worked for me.

This seems to be a problem with Node > 16.