# React Native Node

Tags: node.js, react-native

**Could not start metro bundler**

Getting following error while executing
command :  `npx react-native start`
Node Version : v17.3.0

Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Answer (score 0):

You can find solution for this question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

This error is occuring in Node.js 17. Downgrade your node version to an older version (~16).