# I am trying to create a React Native App with vs code but I have some errors

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

So this type of the error. How to solve this

> Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10)
> at stableHash (/home/shavkat/Android/AwesomeProject/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stableHash.js:19:8)
> at Object.getCacheKey (/home/shavkat/Android/AwesomeProject/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:593:7)
> at getTransformCacheKey (/home/shavkat/Android/AwesomeProject/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/getTransformCacheKey.js:24:19)
> at new Transformer (/home/shavkat/Android/AwesomeProject/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:48:9)
> at /home/shavkat/Android/AwesomeProject/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:22:29 {
> opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
> library: 'digital envelope routines',
> reason: 'unsupported',
> code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
> }

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your node version.
try this [solution on github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11708) and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is two option now -

1. Try to uninstall Node.js version 17+ and reinstall the Node.js version 16+
2. Open terminal and paste these as described :

Linux & Mac OS (windows git bash)-

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Windows command prompt-

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Reference [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69699772/1283345)