# Why do I get this error: Couldn't find the node_modules state file - running an install might help (findPackageLocation)?

Tags: console, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I tried a lot, but my projects don't run with yarn, while already worked(made with create-react-app).

I tried: `yarn install` - `npm install --global yarn` - `npm update --global yarn` -  `yarn version apply` and ect.

when I run `yarn start` then:

[image]

**Edit1:** When I create a new project(with *create-react-app*), not occur any error. It gives an error only for the *previous projects*.

I already did `yarn install` for those directories, and `yarn start` worked.
So run `yarn install` doesn't fix that. Although when I run `run install` again, it gives this error:

[image]

**Edit2:** When I remove `node_modules` and `.yarn` and `yarn.lock`, then run `yarn install` and then`yarn start`, it gives another error:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should run

```
yarn install
```

**before running any npm script** (yarn start). It works when you use create-react-app because it installs dependencies by itself.

About the digital envelope error, You get this error because of the NodeJS version (most likely). If you use the latest LTS downgrade to the previous LTS version. You can read more here: [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported) Let me know how that goes –

Comment: Thanks. But I did it already. So installed dependencies. I updated the question.

Comment: Can you try deleting the `node_modules` folder and running yarn install && yarn start again?

Comment: Thanks again. Only `node_modules`? (how about `.yarn or yarn.lock?`). I deleted it now, but it gives the same error again.

Comment: You get this error because of the NodeJS version (most likely). If you use the latest LTS downgrade to the previous LTS version. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported
Let me know how that goes

Comment: Done, happy to help @ArmanEbrahimi

Comment: @Tasos Please bolden the sentence _before running any npm script_ as this is true **even if** the npm script **is** `yarn install`, as in npm script: `"ci": "yarn install"`.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error due to trying to use an older version Yarn v1 that was installed by default with a stable Node.js 16.x version when I already had Yarn v3 configuration files in the repository, and this was causing conflicts.

I was trying to create a Docker container for an existing repository that already had the following files:

- .yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs
- .yarnrc.yml
- .nvmrc

**.nvmrc**

```
lts/gallium
```

This corresponds to Node.js LTS v16.18.0

**.yarnrc.yml**

```
nodeLinker: node-modules

plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-interactive-tools.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-interactive-tools"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs
```

So I created a Dockerfile, but when it ran `yarn run start`, it returned the same error `Usage Error: Couldn't find the node_modules state file - running an install might help (findPackageLocation)`

After some investigating I realised that the [node:gallium-alpine pre-built Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/node/gallium-alpine/images/sha256-34d5b3bc90f9beb47e7eb14c17837c9d393eb2524b34c9421b1d675ba05b69b2?context=explore) was using Yarn v1 (1.22.19), but the contents of the .yarnrc.yml file indicated that Yarn v3 may be required and was possibly causing a conflict.

So I simply followed these [Yarn instructions](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install) to install its Corepack and the latest Yarn 3.3.0 and also installed Git since it used that.

I renamed .yarnrc.yml to .yarnrc.yml.old so it wouldn't be used or cause conflicts.

Then I re-generated .yarnrc.yml and the .yarn folder so it would have Yarn 3.3.0 instead of 3.1.1 by running:

```
yarn policies set-version 3.3.0
```

But this command only added a line with the new version `yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.3.0.cjs` to the file, so it was necessary to add the remainder of the .yarnrc.yml.old to the re-generated .yarnrc.yml file too. I could then remove .yarnrc.yml.old
I have included the .dockerignore file too for reference.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:gallium-alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add git
COPY package.json .
COPY .env ./

# copy all except shown in .dockerignore
COPY . .

RUN corepack enable && corepack prepare yarn@stable --activate && yarn set version 3.3.0 && yarn install

CMD ["yarn", "run", "start"]
```

**.dockerignore**

```
.git
node_modules
build
Dockerfile
.dockerignore
.gitignore
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this error for a LONG time in my ci/cd pipeline.

`yarn install` was failing to properly complete, but it exited with a `0` (success). Since it failed to properly install, it couldn't find the state file.

TLDR: ensure `yarn install` properly completes

Answer (score 0):

I had accidentally ran `yarn` in a repo that was setup to use npm, which silently mutated my global yarnrc file, causing this error.

My solution was updating the yarnrc file in the repo to contain the entry:

```
nodeLinker: pnp
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael. It was fixed by changing the version of nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Running `yarn install` before running any command to start the project did the trick for me . I still do not know how this happened