# How do I fix: details.family.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, testcafe

I am trying to run a Testcafe test but get the following Error. This used to work until I recently updated npm and Node.

```
 npm test

> e2e-tests@1.0.0 test
> node index.js test

TypeError: details.family.toLowerCase is not a function
    at C:\mac\github\e2e-tests\node_modules\ip\lib\ip.js:385:39
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at C:\mac\github\e2e-tests\node_modules\ip\lib\ip.js:384:37
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ip.address (C:\mac\e2e-tests\node_modules\ip\lib\ip.js:379:37)
    at Proxy.getIPAddress (C:\mac\e2e-tests\node_modules\endpoint-utils\index.js:109:15)
    at getValidHostname (C:\mac\e2e-tests\node_modules\testcafe\lib\index.js:26:34)
    at createTestCafe (C:\mac\e2e-tests\node_modules\testcafe\lib\index.js:71:9)
    at async run (C:\mac\e2e-tests\test-runner.js:40:20)
    at async testRunner (C:\mac\e2e-tests\test-runner.js:117:10)
    at async start (C:\mac\e2e-tests\index.js:9:22)
```

Comment: `details.family` is probably not a string. run a `console.log(typeof details.family)`

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43072) with version 18 of node, interacting with the [ip package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip) (used in lots of popular libraries like [Storybook](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/18010) and [next ui](https://github.com/nextui-org/nextui/issues/498)).

You can try [over-riding](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) to use the latest version of `ip`:

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "ip": "1.1.8"
  }
}
```

But - in my case at least - I ran into [further issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported) with that approach. The only "fix" for now is to downgrade to use the long-term support (LTS) version of node/npm (currently [16.15.1](https://nodejs.org/en/)) rather than 17/18. I highly recommend [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), which will let you just do `nvm install lts`.

Comment: I had updated the ip package yesterday, which fixed this issue, but other issues popped up

Comment: Similarly "resolutions": { "ip": "1.1.8" } works as well for me.