# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported in my pod

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, skaffold

I am getting an unfamiliar error that is keeping my k8s cluster from starting when I run `skaffold dev`.

> ➜  ticketing git:(master) ✗ kubectl logs client-depl-d86b58456-tv8l2
>
> > client@1.0.0 dev
> > next
>
> Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run: npx
> browserslist@latest --update-db ready - started server on
> http://localhost:3000 node:internal/crypto/hash:67   this[kHandle] =
> new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
> ^
>
> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
> at module.exports (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
> at handleParseError (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
> at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
> at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
> at /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
> at iterateNormalLoaders (/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
> at Array. (/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4) {
> opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope
> routines::initialization error' ],   library: 'digital envelope
> routines',   reason: 'unsupported',   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
> }
>
> Node.js v18.3.0

I did run this command: `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`, that did not solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to go inside the `package.json` file of my frontend client application and change the start script to `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider next dev`

Error was documented here:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40455

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Using the current LTS: node 18.12.1:   electron: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

Answer (score 1):

```
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
```

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded the Node.js version I was using to `v16.13.0` and so far it's working for me.

If you are using `NVM` (Node Version Manager), perform the installation using the commands:

1. `nvm install 16.13.0`
2. `nvm use 16.13.0`

Answer (score 0):

**Warning! Many other answers say to downgrade the Node.js version**
I had this problem yesterday and this worked for me:

Go to the `package.json` file in your code and edit the webpack version to this:

"webpack": "^5.64.4"

This version fixed the error.