# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)

Tags: node.js, docker, version, envelope

after building my react docker image I tried to run `docker run image_name`
and after that the log throw this error

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

my docker file is as follows

```
FROM node:18-alpine
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./frontend/package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY ./frontend .
COPY ./images .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I am expecting this might be a node version issue, but I am not quite sure about the error, can anybody explain what this error is about and how I can resolve? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Comment: as an environment variable NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider works for me...

Answer (score 32):

[Node.js v17 moved to OpenSSL v3.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v17.0.0/#openssl-3-0).

You could try switching to v16, or set `ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--openssl-legacy-provider"` in your Dockerfile, or update your `start` script in `package.json` to use `react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start` (or similar depending on your specific start script).

There is an issue you can follow here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11708

Comment: I got: `electron: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS`

Comment: "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start", that did it for me.

Comment: Neither downgrading node nor using the legacy provider is a secure option.

Answer (score 19):

To **start** your application:

update your start script in `package.json` to use

```
react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start
```

To **build** your application:

update your build script in `package.json` to use

```
react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem on Heroku. During the build phase, I got the same error. To solve it, I just had to set as an environment variable:

```
NODE_OPTIONS="--openssl-legacy-provider"
```

Answer (score 4):

After a deep search I come up with this solution.

What was the issue?
The issue was the difference between my Node Version and React js version.

Node.js v18.4.0 
"react":"^16.12.0"

**Solution:**

1. Make Sure that you have nvm installed in you machine if you don't here is the link [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
2. In your Project terminal type: **nvm ls** (You should see a list as showed below )
   [nvm ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJvms.png)
3. Type : **nvm use v16.15.1** choose a version that fits you

[If you don't have any nvm installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSw3W.png)

**Note: After install nvm You MUST RESTART THE TERMINAL OR CLOSE AND OPEN in order to see nvm version**

Answer (score 3):

So, I was running `npm run dev` to do my development, and my package.json looked like:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
...
```

So, I changed that line to:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node --openssl-legacy-provider ./node_modules/.bin/next dev",
```

and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

**Cause**

Before Node 17.x versions, It uses OpenSSL 2 version. NodeJS uses OpenSSL for hash functionality code. The OpenSSL 3 disables MD4, Due to that Nodejs is broken in the latest Nodejs versions.

**Solution**

1. Linux users:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

2. Windows users:

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

3. You can add: `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` to npm scripts.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me after installing the latest Node version/18.15 on my machine while using angular v 12.2.14. So, I was supposed to uninstall the latest node and downgrade it to an older version/v14.21.3 which is compatible with the angular version. Used : https://unpkg.com/browse/@angular/core@12.0.0/package.json  for compatibility check.

Comment: Similar issue here:
So my global Angular projects (CLI 14 & 15) & the entire machine use Node V18, and the project causing this error is written in Angular CLI V11.

Do you think downgrading my entire global Node to say V16 is any better idea?
Maybe upgrade this project's Node or sth?

Comment: @JacobOkelloOkomo, Make sure there are no other projects using the global version and also check the compatibility link first.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use node v16, try NVM for switching between versions easily.

Answer (score 0):

I changed node version `node:16.3.0-alpine` and it worked
however can any body explain `digital envelope routines` please

Comment: This site gave a pretty good explanation: https://itsmycode.com/error-digital-envelope-routines-unsupported/

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that before Node 17.x versions, It uses OpenSSL 2 version. NodeJS uses OpenSSL for hash functionality code. The OpenSSL 3 disables MD4, hence Node.js is broken in the latest Node.js versions.

[Node.js v17 moved to OpenSSL v3.0.](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v17.0.0/#openssl-3-0)

For Next.js / TypeScript project, I have to change the following `dev` script to use the legacy provider in `package.json` for it to work:

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  ...
},
```

To be:

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "node --openssl-legacy-provider ./node_modules/.bin/next dev",
  ...
},
```

---

Or with `start` script:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "next",
  ...
},
```

To be:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "node --openssl-legacy-provider ./node_modules/.bin/next",
  ...
},
```

Answer (score -1):

On your Vs code Terminal. Enter the following:

`$env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--openssl-legacy-provider"`

`npm run start`

and press enter key

Answer (score -2):

Check package.json, under the script I have,

> "scripts": {
> "start": "expo start",
> "android": "expo start --android",
> "ios": "expo start --ios",
> "web": "expo start --web"   }

in terminal run

> expo start -web