# The default project created by preact-cli "^3.4.2" doesn't run

Tags: node.js, webpack, npx, preact, preact-cli

I'm trying to start a preact project. But the default template created by preact-cli doesn't run. Here's what I did:

```
npx preact-cli create default my-project
cd my-project
npm install # this is not necessary I think
npm run dev
```

This results in an error message:

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
```

Some versions:

- npx and npm are 8.12.1
- node is v18.12.1

operating system:

```
Distributor ID: Pop
Description:    Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

**Online version on Stackblitz:**

To make the question easier to answer, I created an online example on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-zby5qu?file=src%2Findex.js

This works!

As a first attempt at solving my problem, I copied the package-lock.json file from stackblitz to my local machine and reinstalled dependencies. But the problem persists.

So it seems that this is related to my local machine.

**Related questions:**

This question advises to switch to Node version 16: [Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73144960/error-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported-at-new-hash-nodei)
And this issue https://github.com/matiasdelellis/facerecognition/issues/613 says that an outdated version of react-scripts can cause the problem.

By now Node 18.13 is the LTS version, I don't want to downgrade to 16.
And as far as I can see, I have the latest version of preact-cli. From my package-lock file:

```
"node_modules/preact-cli": {
  "version": "3.4.4",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/preact-cli/-/preact-cli-3.4.4.tgz",
```

The latest version has been published 3 days ago: https://www.npmjs.com/package/preact-cli?activeTab=readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying [my answer](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/issues/1773) from `preact-cli`'s repo:

Preact-CLI v3 is built upon Webpack v4, which does not support newer versions of Node out-of-the-box. Breaking change in Node caused a lot of ecosystem issues.

However, you don't need to downgrade; instead, you can set `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`. If you're on a non-Windows system, that can be done by making the following alteration to your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider preact watch"
    "build": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider preact build"
  }
}
```

We do have a prerelease published for CLI, available as `4.0.0-next.1`. If you wish to use it, I'd recommend initializing a new project with the following:

```bash
$ [npm init / yarn create] preact-cli default my-project
```