# envelope routines::unsupported at compiling smart contract with truffle

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

i am trying to compile my smart contract using truffle but i get this error msg :

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at hash160 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:249:1)
    at HDKey.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:50:1)
    at Function.HDKey.fromMasterSeed (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:194:1)
    at Function.fromMasterSeed (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/ethereumjs-wallet/dist/hdkey.js:19:1)
    at Object.getAccountsInfo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/mnemonics/mnemonic.js:48:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/develop/run.js:39:1)
    at runCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command-utils.js:201:1)
Truffle v5.5.28 (core: 5.5.28)
Node v16.15.0
```

what is the issue ? how can i solve it ? hints: i've reinstall nodejs in my laptop but without result .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Comment: no i already has node 16