# Console Goerli not functioning on Truffle - This version of µWS is not compatible with your Node.js build

Tags: node.js, ethereum, truffle

When i try to run npx truffle console --network goerli to start the console and then migrate my contracts on goerli testnet using truffle, I get the following error.

```
MacBook-Pro sample-nftrender % npx truffle console --network go
erli
This version of µWS is not compatible with your Node.js build:

Error: Cannot find module './uws_darwin_x64_102.node'
Falling back to a NodeJS implementation; performance may be degraded.


Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10)
    at hash160 (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:249:21)
    at HDKey.set (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:50:24)
    at Function.HDKey.fromMasterSeed (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:194:20)
    at Function.fromMasterSeed (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/ethereumjs-wallet/src/hdkey.ts:13:36)
    at HDWalletProvider.checkBIP39Mnemonic (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/@truffle/hdwallet-provider/src/index.ts:327:35)
    at new HDWalletProvider (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/@truffle/hdwallet-provider/src/index.ts:108:12)
    at Object.provider (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/truffle-config.js:91:24)
    at Object.getProvider (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/index.js:20:1)
    at Object.create (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/index.js:13:1)
    at TruffleConfig.get [as provider] (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/config/dist/configDefaults.js:275:1)
    at Object.detect (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/environment/environment.js:19:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/console/run.js:29:1)
    at runCommand (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command-utils.js:201:1)
Truffle v5.5.30 (core: 5.5.30)
Node v17.8.0
```

My truffle config file is:

```
/**
 * Use this file to configure your truffle project. It's seeded with some
 * common settings for different networks and features like migrations,
 * compilation, and testing. Uncomment the ones you need or modify
 * them to suit your project as necessary.
 *
 * More information about configuration can be found at:
 *
 * https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration
 * 
 * Hands-off deployment with Infura
 * --------------------------------
 *
 * Do you have a complex application that requires lots of transactions to deploy?
 * Use this appproach to make deployment a breeze ️:
 *
 * Infura deployment needs a wallet provider (like @truffle/hdwallet-provider)
 * to sign transactions before they're sent to a remote public node. 
 * Infura accounts are available for free at : https://infura.io/register
 *
 * You'll need a mnemonic - the twelve word phrase the wallet uses to generate
 * public/private key pairs. You can store your secrets  in a .env file. 
 * In your project root, run `$ npm install dotenv`. 
 * Create .env (which should be .gitignored) and declare your MNEMONIC 
 * and Infura PROJECT_ID variables inside.
 * For example, your .env file will have the following structure:
 * 
 * MNEMONIC = <Your 12 phrase mnemonic>
 * PROJECT_ID = <Your Infura project id>
 * 
 * Deployment with Truffle Dashboard (Recommended for best security practice)
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * 
 * Are you concerned about security and minimizing rekt status ?
 * Use this method for best security:
 * 
 * Truffle Dashboard lets you review transactions in detail, and leverages 
 * MetaMask for signing, so there's no need to copy-paste your mnemonic. 
 * More details can be found at : 
 * 
 * https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/using-the-truffle-dashboard/
 */

// require('dotenv').config();
// const { MNEMONIC, PROJECT_ID } = process.env;

// const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
require('dotenv').config()

const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

const mnemonic = process.env.MNEMONIC
const clientURL = process.env.ETH_CLIENT_URL
module.exports = {
  /**
   * Networks define how you connect to your ethereum client and let you set the
   * defaults web3 uses to send transactions. If you don't specify one truffle
   * will spin up a managed Ganache instance for you on port 9545 when you
   * run `develop` or `test`. You can ask a truffle command to use a specific
   * network from the command line, e.g
   *
   * $ truffle test --network <network-name>
   */

  networks: {
    // Useful for testing. The `development` name is special - truffle uses it by default
    // if it's defined here and no other network is specified at the command line.
    // You should run a client (like ganache, geth, or parity) in a separate terminal
    // tab if you use this network and you must also set the `host`, `port` and `network_id`
    // options below to some value.
    //
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
     },
    //
    // An additional network, but with some advanced options…
    // advanced: {
    //   port: 8777,             // Custom port
    //   network_id: 1342,       // Custom network
    //   gas: 8500000,           // Gas sent with each transaction (default: ~6700000)
    //   gasPrice: 20000000000,  // 20 gwei (in wei) (default: 100 gwei)
    //   from: <address>,        // Account to send transactions from (default: accounts[0])
    //   websocket: true         // Enable EventEmitter interface for web3 (default: false)
    // },
    //
    // Useful for deploying to a public network.
    // Note: It's important to wrap the provider as a function to ensure truffle uses a new provider every time.
     goerli: {
       provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, clientURL),
      network_id: 5,       // Goerli's id
      confirmations: 2,    // # of confirmations to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
       timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
      skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
     },
    //
    // Useful for private networks
    // private: {
    //   provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, `https://network.io`),
    //   network_id: 2111,   // This network is yours, in the cloud.
    //   production: true    // Treats this network as if it was a public net. (default: false)
    // }
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters, etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.17",      // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      // settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
      //  optimizer: {
      //    enabled: false,
      //    runs: 200
      //  },
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      // }
    }
  },

  // Truffle DB is currently disabled by default; to enable it, change enabled:
  // false to enabled: true. The default storage location can also be
  // overridden by specifying the adapter settings, as shown in the commented code below.
  //
  // NOTE: It is not possible to migrate your contracts to truffle DB and you should
  // make a backup of your artifacts to a safe location before enabling this feature.
  //
  // After you backed up your artifacts you can utilize db by running migrate as follows:
  // $ truffle migrate --reset --compile-all
  //
  // db: {
  //   enabled: false,
  //   host: "127.0.0.1",
  //   adapter: {
  //     name: "sqlite",
  //     settings: {
  //       directory: ".db"
  //     }
  //   }
  // }
};
```

I am trying to upload an ERC721 smart contract on Goerli. Where is the issue? Is it an issue with the node version?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error

```
error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
```

and fixed it  [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

change your node version to

```
// current latest stable version= v18.12.1
nvm install --lts
```

or use node-16