# installed some dependencies, but now npm start doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app that I created with npx create-react-app. I have been workin on this app for a few weeks and decided to try to add a backend. I installed mongoose, express, and nodemon, and I can see them in my dependencies, but now when I use npm start, it opens up my browser and sends me to localhost:3000 but the app doesn't load. just an error saying this site cant be reached, local host refused to connect. Can anyone help me figure out how to get my app properly running again? [image: here is a picture of terminal output when I run the command]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Comment: Can you please add some code ? especially the index.jsx / app.jsx file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete node modules and install dependencies again similarly you can use  `npm ci` will do the same.