# How to yarn build on Dockerfile

Tags: docker, nuxt.js

I try to build a Docker image executing the code:

docker build . -t <YOUR_DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME>/my-nuxt-project

It is about a nuxt.js project but when I run the code I receive the following error:

```
Step 5/13 : RUN yarn build
 ---> Running in 4dd3684952ba
yarn run v1.22.19
$ nuxt build
ℹ Production build
ℹ Bundling for server and client side
ℹ Target: server
ℹ Using components loader to optimize imports
ℹ Discovered Components: .nuxt/components/readme.md
✔ Builder initialized
✔ Nuxt files generated
ℹ Compiling Client

node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at /app/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.12.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

This is the Dockerfile that I am using. I am following the nuxt documentation to build the image.

```
FROM node:lts as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN yarn install \
  --prefer-offline \
  --frozen-lockfile \
  --non-interactive \
  --production=false

RUN yarn build

RUN rm -rf node_modules && \
  NODE_ENV=production yarn install \
  --prefer-offline \
  --pure-lockfile \
  --non-interactive \
  --production=true

FROM node:lts

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app  .

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Anyone knows how to debug it?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported

Comment: No, it did not work! I added the instructions within scripts, but the same error appeared 

 "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "start": "nuxt --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "generate": "nuxt --openssl-legacy-provider generate",
    "test": "jest"
  },

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` as docker environment variable. So your `Dockerfile` should be like this. Try rebuilding your `Dockerfile` after this change.

```
FROM node:lts as builder

WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

COPY . .

RUN yarn install \
  --prefer-offline \
  --frozen-lockfile \
  --non-interactive \
  --production=false

RUN yarn build

RUN rm -rf node_modules && \
  NODE_ENV=production yarn install \
  --prefer-offline \
  --pure-lockfile \
  --non-interactive \
  --production=true

FROM node:lts

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app  .

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Comment: Hi, Dulaj

Thanks a lot! It is working perfectly 

The container is running ;)

Comment: Got below error @Dulaj

     ```=> ERROR [3/9] RUN yarn install   --prefer-offline   --frozen-lockfile   --non-interactive   --production=false                                                        0.2s
    ------
     > [3/9] RUN yarn install   --prefer-offline   --frozen-lockfile   --non-interactive   --production=false:
    #5 0.196 + yarn install --prefer-offline --frozen-lockfile --non-interactive --production=false
    #5 0.208 /bin/bash: line 1: yarn: command not found
```

Comment: What is the image that you are using? @Karthik