# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported while trying to build a vue-electron project

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

i was trying to create a vue-electron project via electron-builder and I got this error:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ vue-cli-service electron:serve
 INFO  Starting development server...


 DONE  Compiled successfully in 3437ms                                                                                                        00:29:29


  App running at:

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run yarn build.

-  Bundling main process...node:internal/crypto/hash:67
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10)
    at module.exports (D:\coding\JavaScript\Vue\electro\vue3-electron\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\coding\JavaScript\Vue\electro\vue3-electron\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (D:\coding\JavaScript\Vue\electro\vue3-electron\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at D:\coding\JavaScript\Vue\electro\vue3-electron\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at D:\coding\JavaScript\Vue\electro\vue3-electron\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at D:\coding\JavaScript\Vue\electro\vue3-electron\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\coding\JavaScript\Vue\electro\vue3-electron\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (D:\coding\JavaScript\Vue\electro\vue3-electron\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (D:\coding\JavaScript\Vue\electro\vue3-electron\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at D:\coding\JavaScript\Vue\electro\vue3-electron\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at D:\coding\JavaScript\Vue\electro\vue3-electron\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```

I appreciate if someone can help me.

I tried to add

```
--openssl-legacy-provider
```

to the serve command but it didn't help me and I also tried different Node.js version (17,18,19)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Answer (score 0):

I answered a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75434013/20130767

In summary there's two solutions:

- **Quick and Dirty** (not recommended), install Node.js v16. However this will expose your build to security threats that were patched in Node.js v18
- **Proper way**, upgrade your webpack packages from version 4.x.x to 5.0.0