# How to resolve electron error in vuejs vuetify app

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, electron-builder

I'm having trouble getting electron to work in my vuejs/vuetify app.

I'm not sure how to fix the below error.

Here are the versions of the tools I am using:

vue --version = @vue/cli 5.0.4

node -v = v18.12.1

Package.json
"dependencies": {
"core-js": "^3.8.3",
"vue": "^2.6.14",
"vuetify": "^2.6.0"

I created my app with these commands from the admin command line:

-vue create testvue02

-cd testvue02

-vue add vuetify      - I did a 'npm run serve' and this did compile and display the default
vue/vuetify web page

-vue add electron-builder

-npm run electron:serve

Here is the console output:

```
> testvue02@0.1.0 electron:serve
> vue-cli-service electron:serve

INFO  Starting development server...

DONE  Compiled successfully in 12524ms   2:45:44 PM

App running at:
- Local:   http://localhost:8080/
- Network: http://192.168.1.68:8080/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, run npm run build.

-  Bundling main process...node:internal/crypto/hash:71
this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
              ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
 at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
 at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
 at module.exports (C:\Users\johndoe\source\repos\testvue02\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
 at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\johndoe\source\repos\testvue02\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
 at handleParseError (C:\Users\johndoe\source\repos\testvue02\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
 at C:\Users\johndoe\source\repos\testvue02\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
 at C:\Users\johndoe\source\repos\testvue02\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
 at C:\Users\johndoe\source\repos\testvue02\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
 at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\johndoe\source\repos\testvue02\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
 at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\johndoe\source\repos\testvue02\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4) {
 opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Comment: had this issue installing old sass on latest node version, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported

Comment: Probably a NodeJS issue, which version are you on? Try v18 or 16.

Answer (score 1):

## **Cause**

NodeJs v18 closed a security hole in the SSL provider which caused breaking changes in your webpack v4 modules. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027407/20130767

A quick and dirty fix is to downgrade to Node.js v16 but that opens your builds to security threats (explained in reference above). I'll outline a better solution that works with Node.js v18 below.

## **Solution**

I came across the exact same issue and solved it by:

- Upgrading to webpack 5.0.0. Go into your package-lock.json file and change all version 4.x.x webpacks to 5.0.0. (ctrl f and search for "webpack": "4 to find all version 4 webpacks)
- Delete node modules and reinstall using npm i
- Once that's done electron will launch but you may get this error:  "DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in..."  your package.json file of "background.js". Go ahead and delete the 'main' key and value from package.json. Then move "background.js" into your src folder. If you have a "preload.js" file, edit its path accordingly in your "background.js" file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (not with Electron, though, and I am not seeing any Webpack in the repository that I am trying to run) but changing
`vue-cli-service serve`
to
`set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service serve`
solved it for me (on Windows).

Found this possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69962209/what-is-openssl-legacy-provider-in-node-js-v17).

P.S. Note that it above mentioned link it is specified that it depends what is the operating system - if it is Ubuntu the `set` should be changed to `export`.

Hope this helps!