# after remove nop_modules and change windows install latest nodejs my app not working

Tags: node.js, angular

i done

1. windows change format C
2. install node lastest
3. remove node_modules in my project folder
4. i do npm install & all --force and -- other but i see finaly error

and other project also contain node_modules also not loading

```
 ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html
 10% building 3/4 modules 1 active ...js?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-nodenode:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
```

node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53

digital envelope routines::unsupported

Comment: Please do add more details to the question.

Comment: Please share the `node js` version you have installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to install the stable `node.js` version from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). Please refer to [this](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported) answer.

Comment: problem was version of node i return back older version so work fine