# When I ran npm start in my terminal,I got this error

Tags: reactjs

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cSfR.png)

I got this error! like this screenshot.please,thanks for your help...

I also tried npm run start, npm install, but it's does work!help me☺️☺️☺️

Comment: you should refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.