# opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ]

Tags: node.js, vue.js

```
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

I get this error when i switched to node v18

Comment: check out this it already has the solution [StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Comment: Not only is that question for a different error code, most of the answers (including the accepted and most upvoted) are just plain wrong, encouraging downgrades to a vulnerable node version.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Here are two options now -

1. Try to uninstall Node.js version 17+ and reinstall Node.js version 16+

You can re-install the current LTS Node.js version from their [Official site](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). Or more specific downloads from [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm);

You can use NVM (Node Version Manager)

- Linux and Mac users can use this nvm package [link](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
- Windows users can use this nvm package [link](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

2. Open a terminal and paste these as described:

Linux and macOS (Windows Git Bash)-

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Windows command prompt-

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Windows PowerShell-

```
$env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--openssl-legacy-provider"
```

Comment: Yeah this solves it but when I restart the computer I have to do it  again

Comment: `nvm use 16` was what I needed to run.

Comment: (rocky linux) yarn run start now giving me error >> node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

Comment: You can try using a lower version of node, like node 16.19.0

Comment: Bad advise to downgrade such a integral part of your development environment. It might break everything else you work on.

Comment: Thanks for this. I figured it had to be an older version of node issue, but I did `npm update` just in case, and then `nvm use 16` (using `nvm` to manage local node versions), which resolved the issue for the legacy code I'm interacting with. Thanks!

Comment: nvm use 16.13.2  save me. Thanks

Comment: Can we really say that downgrading node to a known vulnerable version and explicitly allowing a vulnerable ssl provider are "solutions" to the question?

Answer (score 51):

Edit the package.json file with below changes:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build"
 
  }
```

Comment: This is a question in a vue environment. Not in react.

Comment: I found the same issue when trying to run a react app, added --openssl-legacy-provider option to my start script instead to downgrade nodejs version

Comment: or maybe try updating react-scripts

Answer (score 32):

Follow these steps on your terminal in the current app directory:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

Installs the npm-check-updates package globally for doing exactly what its name says.

```
ncu
```

This will display the dependencies side-by-side with (an arrow pointing to) their new versions (you are advised to upgrade to) as listed in your package.json file in the current directory.

```
ncu -u
```

This updates those new listed versions on your package.json file and prepares your app for the next step (the updates proper).

```
npm update
```

or

```
npm install
```

Either of these 2 finally installs the new updates; fixes the problem.

---

NB: I used

```
npm install
```

---

I ran into this issue with an old react.js app I cloned from github but did not want to downgrade to an older node version because I had just upgraded from node v14 to v18.13.0. Again, downgrading is not a security-smart option. Updates are there for numerous reasons; most times, "security reasons", especially in the JavaScript world.

Comment: Many thanks! This is an apt answer to the issue I was facing! :) I also didn't want to downgrade my nodejs version.

Comment: Cheers @mr-possible , pleased to have helped!

Comment: Cheers @Steve Smith.
Glad to have helped.

Comment: As others have said, thank you! I was taking a React course and this was driving me crazy. Everything on my computer was current, but the repo hadn't been updated in 3ish years and that's what the issue was +1

Comment: @stinkysGTI You're most welcome! Have fun tinkering!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution that worked for me.

- install nvm. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/
- `nvm install <version>` . For my case, I had to downgrade from node v18 to v16. `nvm install 16.20.2`
- then `nvm use 16` to use the older node version.

Answer (score 1):

Just update your react-scripts package to latest version. It worked for me

```
npm i react-scripts@latest
```