# I have an issue with running npm run dev after updating npm to 8.19.2. Im currently using nuxt 3

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

After updating my npm to 8.19.2 I am no longer able to run `npm run dev`
In my terminal.

I get a response that says `digital envelope routines::unsupported` when I try to run the nuxt.js project for development.

```
node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
```

```
ode:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
```

I have tried downgrading to npm 8.12.0 and below but It does nothing to fix the problem.

Comment: The problem isn't your npm version, it's an incompatibility between your version of SSL and your version of Node, which probably also got updated. See: [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Comment: You're running Node v18? If not, you should be.