# whenever i start the development server in reactjs by using the command npm run start the development server dosent start instead it gives me an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compiler-errors, runtime-error, syntax-error

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\util\\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule.\_initBuildHash (C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\loader-runner\\lib\\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\loader-runner\\lib\\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\loader-runner\\lib\\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\util\\createHash.js:135:53)     
    at NormalModule.\_initBuildHash (C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModule.js:452:10
    at C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\NormalModule.js:323:13
    at C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\loader-runner\\lib\\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\loader-runner\\lib\\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\loader-runner\\lib\\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\\Complete web development bootcamp\\React Course\\textutils\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: \[ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' \],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

I tried editing changing the code, even tried ChatGPT but still didn't get any solution. I even deleted the node_modules folder and installed it again. I was expecting the development server to start but still it didnt

Comment: What about uninstalling node entirely (not just the modules), rebooting your machine, installing node again, installing the modules you need, etc?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported

Comment: Thank you for sharing this article Dave. I installed the nodejs (16.9.0) version and my development server is working fine now.