# The development server returned response error code: 500

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native, geofencing

I encounter this error only happend on my PC. I tried on my other PC and it worked normally. This app is to make Geofencing app that have notif.
This error always happend when I run the project using npm run android.

This is the metro looks like [image]

This is the Android Simulator looks like

[image]
[image]

I tried searching how to fix it but I cant find the one who works

Comment: have you tried this solution?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69699772/5292901

Comment: @SaeidDoroudi yeah i tried that also :D