# Error appears when trying to run npm run watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am currently working on the backend development of a software made with Electron. So, I wanted to add the React JS library to facilitate the insertion of data from a python program and the refreshment of the window except that while testing this code that I found on this link : https://github.com/Jerga99/electron-react-boilerplate .I have an error when I run the npm run watch command and I can't figure out where it comes from?

Here is the error:

```
> electron-react-app@1.0.0 watch
> webpack --config webpack.common.js --watch


webpack is watching the files…

node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\electron-react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)    
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\electron-react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\electron-react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)     
    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\electron-react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\electron-react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\electron-react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\electron-react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\electron-react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\electron-react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at context.callback (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\electron-react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\electron-react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:44:71 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.12.0
```

Regards,

Comment: Did you have a search for "new hash digital envelope routines::unsupported"? For example [I got this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported), [and this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532). Do they apply to your problem?

Comment: Thanks I downloaded version 16 of node.js and it worked but I can't figure out what this is due to?

Comment: Yes these post answer my question.