# Error 'digital envelope' when starting 1.0.0-rc2 AGE Viewer

Tags: node.js, linux

One of my friend facing this error while installing Age-Viewer.

Screenshots

Node.js v18.12.1
Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at handleParseError (D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
at D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
at D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
at D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
throw err;
^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
at D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
at D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at D:\workspace\tools\age-viewer\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
ERROR: "front" exited with 1.

Desktop (please complete the following information):

```
OS: Windows
Browser: Microsoft Edge
Version: 108.0.1462.54
```

You can get Age-Viewer from: https://github.com/apache/age-viewer

Cannot start AGE Viewer 1.0.0-rc2, by following README.md.
According to [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-)
envelope-routinesunsupported , I added --openssl-legacy-provider in frontend/package.json script start, but didn't work.

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

```
npm run setup
npm run start
```

Expected behavior
A clear and concise description of what you expected to happen.

I use Node.js v18.12.1

The given solutions are not specifically for Age-Viewer .

Comment: There are no screenshots available although mentioned in the question. You'd find better help on this if you create an issue on the AgeViewer repo.

Comment: Yes I have found the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution as Age-Viewer is not supporting node greater then 14 therefore getting this error. If I installed the node js 14.16.0 it will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the OpenSSL library that is being used in the project.

Here are a few steps you could follow to troubleshoot the problem:

1. Make sure that npm and Node.js are updated to the latest version.
2. Clear the cache in npm using the `npm cache clean -f` command.
3. Take a look at the 'package.json' file to see if there are any dependencies that need to be taken care of.