# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported (Node.js v19.4.0)

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at module.exports (D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:386:16)      
    at handleParseError (D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:434:10)
    at D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:466:5
    at D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:327:12
    at D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)       
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)       
    at D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)        
    at Array.<anonymous> (D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at module.exports (D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:386:16)
    at D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:418:10
    at D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:293:13
    at D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v19.4.0
PS D:\web development\frontend\react\reduxbasic>
```

how to solve this error

Comment: It looks like it is caused by an incompatible version of webpack and crypto you should check your dependencies and update them to compatible version

Answer (score 27):

You can use the following command in Unix:

`export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`

For Windows, use this command instead:

`set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`

**Note that you don't need to downgrade your Node.js version to resolve this issue.**

---

If you're using `react-script`, you may also need to upgrade it to the latest version by running:

`npm i react-scripts@latest`

Or you can replace the following line in the `package.json` file:

From:
`"start": "react-scripts start"`

To:
`"start": "react-scripts start --openssl-legacy-provider"`

Comment: Tnx much for set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider, this worked for me. Setting it in package.json did not work for me.

Comment: I assume this is not safe to use in prod right? I am receiving this error when trying to build for serverless framework `from Terser Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported`

Comment: Thank you, you get another up vote :)  I ran into this using a repo for a course, got up to the point of using npm start and this error cropped up.

What a relief to see the code compiled after this simple line of code.

Where can I read up more on this so that I better understand why this happens.  Don't want to be a code monkey here.

Comment: @user1585204 see in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027407/8353201

Answer (score 9):

## My fix

---

You have to use `md5` in this file `md4` is the default, but it will not work.

Crypto is a tool from Node.js
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatehashalgorithm-options

I know is not ideal, but is working without an issue now, until I delete the node_modules folder

[image]

### With this versions

```bash
➜  ~ node -v 
v19.8.1
➜  ~ npx react-native -v  
10.2.0
➜  ~ react-native --version
4.14.0
➜  ~ npm -v
9.5.1
```

### my error

[image: my error]

Answer (score 6):

**Above steps don't work for me, running these commands in root of the project solved the issue .**

1. `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`
2. `npm start`

*For more solutions on this problem : [visit this article](https://sebhastian.com/error-0308010c-digital-envelope-routines-unsupported/)*

Answer (score 5):

If you are on node>=18, please put this in webpack config on top.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const crypto_orig_createHash = crypto.createHash;
crypto.createHash = algorithm => crypto_orig_createHash(algorithm == "md4" ? "sha256" : algorithm);
```

Comment: thank you @Imtiyaz Shaikh! This worked for me on node 21... but why does it work? And is it safe?

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and this resolved it:

```
npm i react-scripts@latest
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

***My Problem***

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
```

***My Solution***

In your package.json: change this line

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

to

```
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
```

**Try this will work. This has resolved my issue.**

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

As I can see you are using `version 19` of node.js (*Not recommended For Most Users*), also mention on official Node.js website.

**Solution:**

1. Go to [Node.js Download Page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. Download `version 18` of node.js (*LTS
   Recommended For Most Users*)  for your OS.
3. Delete node_modules and package_lock file .
4. Run `npm install`.
5. Run your app again .

Problem should be fixed now.

Comment: On version 18.16.0 of Node. Removed node_modules and yarn.lock. Run yarn install again. Problem not resolved.

Comment: This answer might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/76669009/17539341

Answer (score 0):

I also catch this error. In my case I used Node version 20.

This instruction worked for me:

1. Use node version 18;
2. Delete `node_modules` and `package_lock.json` file;
3. Run `npm install react-scripts@latest`.

then my package.json look like:

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the `start` script in your package.json from

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

to

```
"start": "react-scripts start --openssl-legacy-provider",
```

then run the below command in the terminal

```
npm i react-scripts@latest
```

--This works for me like a good one--

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just the version for Node.js is high and it`s not suitable for OpenSSL, so you could install an old version.

Answer (score 0):

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported (Node v20.11.0)

1. change this line

"start": "react-scripts start" to "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
2.Run below command in terminal
npm i react-scripts@latest
it works.
Thanks and regards.