# Problem with yarn installation in react app initially coded in codesandbox

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, codesandbox

I initially coded my react app in codesandbox.io with repository on github. Recently I have cloned the repository to my device and runned in terminal: "yarn install" command. Looks like it installed all node_modules, but terminal throws me some comments which I actually don't know how to fix. Can You please look at it and suggest ?

[image]

This is how my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "trading-blog",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "keywords": [
    "typescript",
    "react",
    "starter"
  ],
  "main": "src/index.tsx",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.10.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.10.16",
    "@mui/material": "5.10.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "@types/react-router": "5.1.19",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.3",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "6.5.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "18.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "typescript": "4.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Comment: There is a lot of answers in it, but the best one is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74138345/5767872), to update "react-scripts" version in packages.json.