# Localhost 3000 refused to connect

Tags: localhost

Good morning guys. I can't connect to the localhost. I tried some stackoverflow recommendations and went through the topics on Git, but still nothing. What I did:
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFDtx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8seA.png)

1. Started from the easiest one  - relaunched my Mac.
2. Checked modules configurations.
3. Tried to change the port to another one.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to changes in the strictness of running without a SSL certificate.

Did you try to change this line in package.json?

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

to

```
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
```

[Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)