# Elixir project cannot build due to Node OpenSSL crypto dependency

Tags: node.js, openssl, elixir

I have an Elixir project running Alpine Linux 3.16 and a few of the apps within the project depend on Node. I'm getting error messages through AWS CodeBuild that

`error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported`

So far I've found a number of threads on this issue including this one: [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

It appears like I need to set Node options to use this flag `--openssl-legacy-provider`

I have tried the following solutions so far without success

1. Putting `ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` in the Dockerfile for broken apps
2. Putting `RUN export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` in the Dockerfile for the broken apps
3. Putting `RUN npm audit fix --force`  within the Dockerfile for the broken apps
4. Changing the package.json in the apps to use `"scripts": { "deploy": "webpack --mode production --openssl-legacy-provider", "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch" }`

So far none of these have worked and I'm looking for any solution to get around this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get it working now by placing

`ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`

at a later stage in the Dockerfile and also upgrading Alpine to 3.17

There's an active thread detailing this issue further: https://github.com/erlang/docker-erlang-otp/issues/428