# Angular error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported if start ng serve

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, intellij-idea

i get this error if i try to start my Angular Application. How can i fix it?

My Framework: IntelliJ

Versions that i use:
Node.js v18.13.0
NPM 9.4.2
Angular CLI: 12.2.18
Node: 18.13.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 9.4.2
OS: win32 x64

the full Error is:

```
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```

Node.js v18.13.0

Comment: please check the solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported