# Nextjs Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, openssl, bundle

I just came back to an old app to continue working on it. It used to work well, but now, if I try to run dev on it, I get that error :

> ```
> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> ```

```
    at /Users/mac/Documents/Documents - macs MacBook Pro/paola-blog/my-project/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:68407:5
node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (/Users/mac/Documents/Documents - macs MacBook Pro/paola-blog/my-project/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:138971:18)
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (/Users/mac/Documents/Documents - macs MacBook Pro/paola-blog/my-project/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:138872:50)
    at OriginalSource.updateHash (/Users/mac/Documents/Documents - macs MacBook Pro/paola-blog/my-project/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack-sources3/index.js:1:10264)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/mac/Documents/Documents - macs MacBook Pro/paola-blog/my-project/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:68468:17)
    at handleParseResult (/Users/mac/Documents/Documents - macs MacBook Pro/paola-blog/my-project/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:68534:10)
    at /Users/mac/Documents/Documents - macs MacBook Pro/paola-blog/my-project/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:68628:4
    at processResult (/Users/mac/Documents/Documents - macs MacBook Pro/paola-blog/my-project/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:68343:11)
    at /Users/mac/Documents/Documents - macs MacBook Pro/paola-blog/my-project/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:68407:5 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v19.3.0
```

Here is package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-next-blog",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "next dev",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "deploy": "next build && next export",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "lint:fix": "next lint --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.17",
    "git": "^0.1.5",
    "gsap": "^3.9.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "next": "^11.0.0",
    "qs": "^6.10.1",
    "react": "17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.0",
    "react-markdown": "^4.2.2",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.6",
    "sass": "^1.49.7"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^11.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.6",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.22"

  }
}
```

Comment: Does [this previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027407/21146235) help at all?

Comment: My bad, I'm sorry. I tried the first time. It didn't. ButI just try again tom be sure and now it worked