# npm start throws exception *digital envelop routines are unsupported*

Tags: node.js

I was assigned a task to work on the front end of a react application but I have faced a very strange error. When I forked and cloned it on my machine, I ran `npm i` for installing the necessary dependencies. After the installation was complete I ran the command `npm start` in order to run the project on my machine and I was returned with an exception. The error message is attached with the question as well, [Error Screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD5nI.png), [ScreenShot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Rny.png). It said digital envelope routines are unsupported.

I searched for the question on Stackoverflow and also followed various instructions but nothing happened. Can someone tell me the solution to the problem and why it might be happening?

Currently, I am using node version 18.16.0.

Comment: Note: It is not recommended to use images in stackoverflow, you should have copied the important message and add it to the question in a code ```sh ``` tag

Comment: Whats your node version? Try to downgrade to 14.16.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run that on your terminal before running start or install command:

```bash
# linux
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
# windows
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Related question:

- [Node.js ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED error when running npm run start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75959563/node-js-err-ossl-evp-unsupported-error-when-running-npm-run-start/75961537#75961537)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing errors in same project on windows.

I deleted the project and then Re-cloned it.

I installed `nvm (Node Version Manager)` and followed these steps:

install the latest version of `Node JS` using the following command

> nvm install latest

it will install the latest version of `Node JS`

the execute the following command to use the latest version.

> nvm use latest

then run `npm i` in both **frontend** and **backend** folder in the project

then install `Node version 14.16.0` it is required for the project, using the command

> nvm install 14.16.0

and

> nvm use 14.16.0

then run

> npm install

in the Cloud-express (root directory)

and the execute the following command

> npm start

these steps worked for me and the project is now running well.

Answer (score 0):

The error message “0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported” occurs when the MD4 algorithm used by Webpack is no longer supported by default in the latest Node.js version. To fix this error, you can upgrade Webpack to version 5 which implements its own MD4 algorithm without depending on Node’s implementation. Another solution is to set the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable to --openssl-legacy-provider when running your development server. The two solutions are explained in detail in the link below.

- [How to fix error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported on NodeJS](https://sebhastian.com/error-0308010c-digital-envelope-routines-unsupported/)
- [error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-error-digital-envelope-routines-unsupported)

Answer (score 0):

This is reaccuse of projects OpenSSL library version is incompatible with your Node.js version installed in your system. It's very simple to solve this error. 
If you're facing error in ReactJS project then just replace your package scripts with these:

```
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
"build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build"
```

If you're facing this type of error in NextJS, then use and replace the package scripts with these:

```
"dev": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && next dev",
"build": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && next build",
"start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && next start",
```