# ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED while run vue js project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, node-modules

I getting below error while run vue js project with node js 18.

```
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```

Wo blogs recommended to pass --openssl-legacy-provider  option while run, but still not working. any other alternative to fix this issue?

Comment: Got answer in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75959563/node-js-err-ossl-evp-unsupported-error-when-running-npm-run-start?rq=2