# My react app suddenly crashed in local server: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, webpack, node-modules

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:386:16)
    at handleParseError (/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:434:10)
    at /Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:466:5
    at /Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:327:12
    at /Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:386:16)
    at /Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:418:10
    at /Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:293:13
    at /Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /Users/parasnagpal0707/Documents/Projects/StalkHub/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

I am getting the following errors

On command line

[image]

while trying to start the app using npm run start.

On Screen

[image]

I am using node version 18 and my dependancies are:

```
{
  "name": "github-search",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.12.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "fusioncharts": "^3.19.0",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-fusioncharts": "^4.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "CI= react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.79.0"
  }
}
```

I tried to fix it by changing react scripts to legacy provider and also used npm audit --fix force multiple times, still no result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Comment: I didnt tried downgrading node but tried all others . its not working .

Comment: it worked now . it was actually a issue in dependancy tree.

Answer (score 0):

It was a issue with webpack , so just remove nodemodules related to webPack and try it again . It works this way .

Comment: What is webpack and why does it cause errors in your react app?

Comment: It manages modules in js , it gets automatically installed with create react app . They were having some issues at that time , now its fine .