# I am trying to run "npm start" command but it throws " Starting the development server... " error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When I run `npm start` in vs code terminal this error occurs and the browser says

> This site can’t be reached

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXgdg.png)
[browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SP40.png)

This error occurred after using these commands :

- npm i -g react-scripts
- npm install react-scripts --save
- npm install
- del node_modules && npm install

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAlOU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question!

I think you will find your solution in this link:

[Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Comment: this link is not useful

Comment: Hmm, I am having difficulties replicating your error.
Have you tried deleting the "package-lock.json" and the "node_modules" folder? 
followed by: 

1) run: npm install
2) run: npm start

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but the error is still there

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade to latest NodeJS version (e.g.: Version 18.16.0)?
It might be a npm cache error, so if upgrading the NodeJS, isn't a possibility try clearing your cache: 
Guide: https://coder-coder.com/npm-clear-cache/

Comment: I upgraded the NodeJS version to 18.16.0. Still, it doesn't work.

Comment: did you clear the cache?
1) run: npm cache clean --force
2) run: npm install

Comment: Yes I did but the problem still persists

Comment: I created new project and pasted my code here and created new package.json, package-lock.json,node_modules files and the project is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Well, I am glad to hear something helped!