# vercel deploy error after upgrade node version to 18: error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vercel

I upgraded my node version to 18 and now I can not deploy my project to vercel because I am getting this error:

```
`Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/vercel/path0/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/vercel/path0/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (/vercel/path0/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/vercel/path0/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/vercel/path0/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:19
  throw err;
  ^
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/vercel/path0/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
Node.js v18.15.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1`
```

My project runs good in my local env, but I can not deploy it

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported