# hi i have a problem in react project.npm start problem?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, openssl, npm-start, pyopenssl

hi i have a problem in react project. i installed node js and python, then set env variables in settings for both,Openssl also installed but when i run npm start i got this error..has anyone experinced this.Starting the development server...

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10) 
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10) 
D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
    at D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
    at D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at D:\CodeBox\master\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Node.js v18.16.0

i installed Openssl and set varilbels of that...not able to run the project?

any installation require anyomore

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Answer (score -1):

Try downgrading your Node version to v16. I suggest using [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) or [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for that, as manually switching Node versions can be a drag.